# LaTeX programming comparison operators

Tags: programming, comparison

The example for the `forloop` package is `\newcounter{ct}\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 5}{\arabic{ct}}`. I need to compare two counters having the first run up to the second. `<=` doesnt work, neither does `\leq` or `...+1`. I know I can solve it with `\not` or `\or`, but those are workarounds. How does it really work?

1. Can I and if so how can I do a "real" `<=`?
2. Can I and if so how can I use formulas (like `\value{a}<\value{b}+1`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No. It is based on TeX's `\ifnum`, and only `<`, `=`, `>` is supported.
2. Use eTeX primitive `\numexpr`:

   ```
   \newcounter{ct} \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < \numexpr\value{page}+10}{\arabic{ct} }
   ```

   Or you can use `etoolbox` package (looks awful for this simple bool expression, I agree):

   ```
   \newcounter{ct}
   \setcounter{ct}{1}
   \whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{ct}}<{\value{page}+10}}}
     {\arabic{ct} \stepcounter{ct}}
   ```

Comment: In the first case, you may want to add `\relax` to be sure to end `\numexpr` at the right place (`\numexpr` will remove it). Otherwise, `\numexpr` may end up trying to expand some code which is placed after that argument. It turns out that `\ifthenelse` has a `\relax` at the right place, but I wouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 6):

The expl3 programming package allows you to use extended comparison operators including `<=` and so on; there's a few ways to perform your specific task here (e.g., also see `\prg_stepwise_inline:nnnn`), but here's one example that uses the ‘do while’ method explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \ct
\int_set:Nn \ct {10}

\bool_while_do:nn
  { \int_compare_p:n { \ct <= 17 } }
  {
    [ \int_use:N \ct ]
    \int_incr:N \ct
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```