# What is the proper method of accessing a counter?

Tags: counters

It seems that there are different ways of accessing counters.  I have been using `\theMyCount` as in this post about [Using counters or macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20909/using-counters-or-macros), but noticed that the arrayjobx package uses `\the\value{MyCount}`.

This post about [LaTeX programming comparison operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/latex-programming-comparison-operators) uses just `\value{MyCount}` but that does not seem to compile for me.

Are there any differences between these different methods of accessing counters?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{MyCount}

\begin{document}

MyCount = \theMyCount

MyCount = \the\value{MyCount}

%MyCount = \value{MyCount}% Does not compile for me.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [whether or not I have to use `\the`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/confused-with-whether-or-not-i-have-to-use-the)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\the\value{MyCounter}` is just a slightly faster way to say `\arabic{MyCounter}`, as the former expands successively to

```
\the\csname c@MyCounter\endcsname
\the\c@MyCounter
```

and the latter to

```
\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@MyCounter\endcsname
\@arabic\c@MyCounter
\number\c@MyCounter
```

TeX rules say that `\the` is essentially equivalent to `\number`. I don't think that the difference in execution time can be significant in a normal document. It's usually better to stick to "official" macros, when they exist, in order to be sure that the result will be stable over time.

Usage of `\theMyCount` may be improper when we are not sure what kind of representation is associated to the counter `MyCount`.

On the other hand, `\theMyCount` *should not* be used in contexts when we are interested in the "abstract" value stored in the counter, so putting in a macro

```
\ifnum\value{MyCounter}>0
```

is correct, while

```
\ifnum\theMyCounter>0
```

is dangerous, because the user might have changed the representation of `MyCounter` when the macro is used.

Answer (score 19):

You should use `\theMyCounter` if you want to output the value in Arabic numerals, Roman numerals, symbols or other format. You can restyle `\theMyCounter` by

```
\renewcommand\theMyCounter{\roman{MyCounter}} % lowercase Roman numerals
```

You should use `\value{MyCounter}` if it is used in an expression. For example

```
\ifnum\value{MyCounter}>5 ... \else ...\fi
\ifthenelse{\value{MyCounter}<4}{...}{...} % ifthen package
\setcounter{AnotherCounter}{\value{MyCounter}}
```

You can use `\the\value{MyCounter}` the same as `\arabic{MyCounter}`. But it is a mixed syntax. You'd better always use `\arabic{MyCounter}` in LaTeX; and if you want to pry, it is the same as `\the\c@MyCounter`.