# When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar

Tags: macros

Since egreg has graciously agreed to not comment at least for a day to [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) :-), I thought I would take advantage of that and post a question about another (non-offical) campaign of egreg: additional `%` at the end of `\newcommand` and similar macros.

### Background:

After starting out with LaTeX and defining numerous macros I ran into  *TeX Capacity exceeded* problems. After considerable time, I was able to come up with an example small enough that reproduced the problem and posted it here:

- [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro)

That and the following provide a good explanation of what is going on:

- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)
- [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces/19955#19955)

So, I got into the habit of adding a `%` at the end of ***every*** line within the preamble, even after `\usepackage{}` and following the last `}` of a `\newcommand`, where is it strictly not necessary. My logic being that I did not see any harm and was easier to just add it rather than try to think about whether it was needed or not.

### Problem:

However, a comment was made in [Defining command containing pagebreak, and boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34538/defining-command-containing-pagebreak-and-boxes/34539#34539):

> Actually four of your % are redundant. ... In some cases a % can even be wrong. :) - [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)

Sometimes, I even added trailing `%` within the document body, but noticed an answer was edited to remove the `%`. For example this answer for [Producing different versions of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22523/producing-different-versions-of-a-document/22569#22569) originally had a trailing `%` after every line. Now, in this case this is not part of the preamble, but again I thought there was no harm in including them.

The only situation I am aware of where there is an issue with a trailing `%` is mentioned at [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines):

```
\show\ 
\show\ %
```

### Question:

I prefer solutions that require less thought, so I tend to include a trailing `%` even though it may not be absolutely necessary.  So, I would like to know when is it harmful to add a trailing `%` in the definitions of `\newcommand` and similar macros?  Are there other cases besides the above `\show`.

---

Here is the MWE: The two macros `\mymacroA` and `\mymacroB` are identical, except for the trailing `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mymacroA[1]{
    #1
}
\newcommand\mymacroB[1]{% <-- This percent is important
    #1% <-- This percent is important
}% This does not appear to be necessary

\begin{document}
 \mymacroA{foo}bar \mymacroA{foo} bar

 \mymacroB{foo}bar \mymacroB{foo} bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your editing of the title has substantially changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: Yeah I realized that there was an inconsistency in the title and the question in the text after reading the initial responses.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Tokenization stage

The general rule<sup>∗</sup> is that spaces after control words (`\par`, for instance) are ignored, while after control symbols (`\!`, for instance) are retained; spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored altogether. Consecutive spaces are transformed into *one* space token but two consecutive end-of-lines become a `\par` (this statement is not fully correct, but not too incorrect for the purposes of this answer).

### After the tokenization stage

There is an obvious intermix between tokenization stage and subsequent processing. In what follows "space" will mean "space token" and I won't care about spaces that have already disappeared, such as those after a control word).

It's now important to know that spaces in the input don't always produce spacing in the output. To understand why, it's necessary to learn some theory.

TeX is always in one of three *modes*: horizontal, vertical or math.<sup>∗∗</sup>

Under normal circumstances spaces do not produce output in vertical and math mode (let's not discuss the very special settings that make them appear).

It's quite easy to tell when TeX enters math mode: as soon as it sees `$` or `$$` (which, in LaTeX parlance, are, respectively `\(` and all the display math environments, initiated by `\[`, `\begin{equation}`, `\begin{align}` and so on). It exits math mode, returning to the previous mode when it sees the closing `$` or `$$` (with similar remarks as before for LaTeX).

Roughly speaking, TeX is in vertical mode at the start of a job or after a `\par` or when it's beginning a `\vbox` or `\vtop` or `\vcenter`; these are started, in LaTeX, by `\parbox` and `\begin{minipage}`. However, spaces in vertical and math mode are *not* suppressed: they are there, but produce no output. This is a cause for some misunderstandings. TeX starts horizontal mode when it sees a character to be typeset, `\noindent`, `\indent` or some other commands, notably `\leavevmode` (this is not an exhaustive list) or when it's starting an `\hbox` (for LaTeX it's `\mbox`, `\makebox`, `\fbox`, `\colorbox`, ... or the `lrbox` environment). In horizontal mode *every* space that's not absorbed by other rules (see later) produces output.

- When TeX is absorbing the preamble of a LaTeX document it is in vertical mode. But a definition such as

  ```
    \newcommand{\foo}{
      bar
    }
  ```

will produce spaces in the output: the above is *equivalent* to

```
    \newcommand{\foo}{ bar }
```

If `\foo` is seen at the beginning of a paragraph, the first space will not produce output (TeX is still in vertical mode), but the second will, as the `b` will trigger horizontal mode. Conversely

```
    \newcommand{\baz}[1]{\parbox{10cm}{
      #1
    }}
```

won't show spurious spaces. The first one, before `#1` does nothing because it's seen in vertical mode; the final one, after `#1` is suppressed because of the final implicit `\par` that ends the `\parbox`.

- A definition such as

  ```
    \newcommand{\myop}{
      \overset{t }{=}
    }
  ```

will not need `%` to protect end-of-lines (translated into spaces), because it will be used in math mode (or will give an error anyway).

The most important (but easy) rule that should be considered is that *tokens in the body of a definition are simply stored and not executed* (they can be expanded in a `\edef` or `\xdef`, but still not *executed*). The execution is performed (after expansion) when the defined macro is *used*. The execution of a space token in vertical or math mode does nothing, in horizontal mode it produces a spacing in the output.

### Numbers and dimensions

There is a place where space tokens have a peculiar behavior. When TeX is looking for a number or a dimension in order to perform an assignment or when expanding `\number` and `\romannumeral`, it expands tokens until an unexpandable token appears *or* a space token is found. In this case, the space is swallowed as part of the process.

This is one aspect to be kept in mind when writing macros. Let's see an example: we want to make a "monthly to-do list". Just a `\parbox` with twelve lines labelled by year and month; a loop seems the best approach, with the year given as argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\monthlycount
\newcommand{\monthlytodo}[1]{\par%
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{10cm}{%
      \monthlycount=1%
      \loop\ifnum\monthlycount<13%
        #1--\number\monthlycount\hrulefill\par%
        \advance\monthlycount by 1%
      \repeat%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\monthlytodo{2013}
\end{document}
```

Try it; this will surprise you with

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
```

Oh, boy! We've made sure that no spurious spaces were inserted by our macro! Why is TeX betraying us? Simple: the input can be written equivalently as

```
\loop\ifnum\monthlycount<13#1--\number\monthlycount
```

and `#1` is replaced by 2013. So our loop checks whether the current value of `\monthlycount` is less than 132013 and stores tokens for the `\parbox` until TeX runs out of memory.

Let's try an amended version:

```
\newcommand{\monthlytodo}[1]{\par
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{10cm}{
      \monthlycount=1
      \loop\ifnum\monthlycount<13
        #1--\number\monthlycount\hrulefill\par
        \advance\monthlycount by 1
      \repeat
    }%
  }%
}
```

Look, ma! No spurious spaces!

[image]

**Exercise 1** Why some lines end with `%` and other lines don't? We now know that `%` is *harmful* after `13` (and also after the `1` in the preceding line).

Technicality: space tokens are looked for but then swallowed also after keywords (such as `by` in the example and the unit names `mm`, `pt` and so on). There are also a few other places, but this answer is already too long. I'll show only how some of the problems can arise also when using LaTeX functions in this context:

```
\newcounter{monthlycount}
\newcommand{\monthlytodo}[1]{\par
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{10cm}{
      \setcounter{monthlycount}{1}
      \loop\ifnum\value{monthlycount}<13
        #1--\arabic{monthlycount}\hrulefill\par
        \stepcounter{monthlycount}
      \repeat
    }%
  }%
}
```

**Exercise 2** Why isn't `%` necessary in lines 4–9 of the code above?

##### Footnotes

<sup>∗</sup> The general rule applies to spaces (and tabs) of category code 10. In verbatim environments, or whenever spaces don't have category code 10, this obviously doesn't apply.

<sup>∗∗</sup> This is, strictly speaking, a lie: there is a circumstance in which it's not in one of these modes, but this case is irrelevant for the discussion.

Comment: So is TeX in vertical mode at the end of each of lines 4-9? At the end of line 4, you've just started a \parbox but not yet fed TeX a character or similar. The same is true at the end of lines 5 and 6? At the end of line 7, you've been in horizontal mode but the \par puts TeX back in vertical mode. It is still in vertical mode at the end of lines 8 and 9?

Comment: @cfr TeX *will be* in vertical mode after executing `\parbox{`, so it will ignore the space token; the instruction in line 5 doesn't start horizontal mode; line 6 ends with a constant required by the syntax, so a trailing space is ignored; there is no space at the end of lines 7 and 9; TeX will be in vertical mode when processing the space at the end of line 8, because of the preceding `\par`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Exercise 1 ... We now know that % is harmful after 13 (and also after the 1 in the preceding line)... The % after the 1 in this line isn't harmful, it is only improper. The `\loop` macro begins with `\def`, this token ends the number scanning.

Comment: @wipet I would avoid expanding `\loop` before the constant has been determined. But the question is why some lines that don't end with a number have no `%`. ;-)

Comment: Exception to "spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored altogether."  Between `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` they are retained.  (How else could one create intelligible code examples?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton added a footnote

Comment: Am I remembering correctly that early in the TeX Book, Knuth says the space after the units of a dimension is optional. So is `%` after a dimension equally harmful? (I know it's OK not to have one, but should I leave a space before a comment?)

Comment: @cfr Yes, that's the same problem, because TeX looks for this space with expansion of the following token.

Answer (score 32):

You should first understand the rules applied to spaces (except inside verbatim of course):

- Multiple spaces including other whitespaces (tab, newline) are taken as one single space token.
  With the exception of two newlines, which form a `\par` instead.
- Spaces after control words (normal macros) are ignored.
  This is because you might need to add a space to separate the macro name from trailing text: e.g. `\relax abc`, because `\relaxabc` would be a different control word.
- Spaces after control characters (macros with a single non-letter, like `\_`, `\`, etc., but not `\a` which is a control word) are not ignored.
  This is because they are only one character long (besides the backslash) and therefore the end of the name is already known.
- Spaces at the beginning of a line are always ignored.
- Spaces in the direct preamble including package and class files are ignored.
  This is a LaTeX specific thing and simply configured so.
- However, spaces inside a macro definition occurring in a preamble are stored as normal *into* the macro.
  That is the reason why you need to use `%` inside macros but not outside of them, e.g. after the closing `}`.
- Spaces terminate the number collecting process of TeX when it assigns a count register or with `\ifnum` or any other number context. That space is then consumed.
  So if you write something like `\mycount=123` you want to have a space or `\relax` after it, otherwise the next macro will be expanded, because TeX is searching for the potential rest of the number.

---

Note that in your `\show` example the `%` is simply there to protect the editor to remove the space as a trailing space turning `\<space>` into `\<newline>`. You don't need to have it there as long the space stays there, but it is just saver.

---

Then there are really some advances situations where TeX allows for an optional space, where you want to add a space so a space which follows is not taken as that optional space. I know this from `\let\dummy=<space>`, which is used to remove a space from the input stream. Often such code is used in a parser loop and removing that space would cause issues, because now the next token is removed, not the space which is taken as the optional space. I encountered situations where a loop can be turned into an endless one just by removing that space. There was an answer which had this included, maybe I find it again.

Comment: Good summary of the rules of spaces. But, if I understand fully, there is no harm in adding the `%` except for the `\mycount=123` where I would need to either have a space before the trailing percent as in `\mycount=123 %` or use `\mycount=123\relax%`

Comment: @PeterGrill: `\mycount=123 %` is fine, but simply `\mycount=123` followed by a newline is fine, too, because it is taken as a space. You don't need a `%` after `\relax`.

Comment: "Note that in your \show example the % is simply there to protect the editor to remove the space as a trailing space turning \<space> into \<newline>." doesn't make sense to me, are you missing a word somewhere? Specifically "to protect the editor to remove" doesn't scan.

Comment: There is a difference between ``\<space><endline>`` and ``\<space>%<endline>``. In the first case one gets `\^^M` (whose usual definition is to expand to ``\<space>``). This is because TeX strips final spaces before appending `^^M`, and this happens before `%` does its job of making TeX ignore it and everything to the end of the line. So in the second case one has really `\<space>`. Note: this assumes the usual value of `\endlinechar`.

Answer (score 12):

> When not to add percent character at end of lines in a `\newcommand`,
>   or similar

You don't need to add percentage signs when you use a convenience environment from the good people of LaTeX3:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
... your definitions here
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Saves typing and conserves percent signs! Answered in the spirit of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question, when the title of the question was as quoted!

Comment: Note that here both `_` and `:` are 'letters', which may be important if you use, for example, LaTeX2e's `\@for` or want math subscripts.

Comment: I adjusted the title of the question: I am interested in when it is harmful to add the `%`. So is there a problem in adding a trailing `%` in the above?

Comment: @JosephWright True, but we should all slowly gravitate our code towards LaTeX3, despite our moaning and groaning about the syntax:).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'm not moaning, only noting something that might otherwise confuse (as the environment does more than just ignore spaces).

Comment: @JosephWright I am moaning and groaning! I don't like too many underscores:). I am glad you made the comment.

Comment: @PeterGrill No it should not be a problem.

Comment: Also note that (as explained in the answer above) you'd better not using TeX-style assignment/number-reading commands (`\ifnum`, `\counter=...`) at all; or if you do, always include a space token `~` after it.