# LaTeX figures side by side

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I want to place 2 images side by side in LaTeX. I have 2 .png files and I don't understand how to do it in LaTeX. I have tried many ways but could not get a good result.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This answer helped me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83665/61609

Answer (score 639):

For two independent side-by-side figures, you can use two `minipage`s inside a `figure` enviroment; for two subfigures, I would recommend the `subcaption` package with its `subfigure` environment; here's an example showing both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` was used only to make my example compilable for everyone; you shouldn't use that option in your actual code.

The `%` (between `\end{subfigure}` and `\begin{subfigure}` or `minipage`) is really important; not suppressing it will cause a spurious blank space to be added, the total length will surpass `\textwidth` and the figures will end up not side-by-side.

Comment: right... but where do you say `minipage` in your latex code?

Comment: @DNA inside the second `figure` environment there are two `minipage`s; one for each of the (independent) images.

Comment: Oh, ok! I guess I am blind!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, the subfigure is giving me an error `ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: @LWZ my example code compiles without errors; something else must be going on in your document and without seeing the actual code, it's hard to tell. Please opena a new fresh question and add to it a minimal version of the document illustrating the problem.

Comment: If one of the images have a multi-line caption then the images are not aligned side-by-side. In this case, use `[t]` option after `\begin{subfigure}`.

Comment: The width of the `subfigure` (`.5\textwidth`) and the width of the `includegraphics` (`.4\linewidth`) seem to get multiplied, is that correct? If you want them both side-by-side so that they fill the entire screen width, setting the graphic's width to full `\textwidth` works better for me.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I cannot get the images to be positioned side by side they are always on top of each other. % character is included, how can this be remedied?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sorry for disturbing, there was a space between the end command and the "%" which was the culprit.

Comment: What does the % mean/do though. Isn't it the comment character? Is it intended to suppress new line in this specific situation? Thanks.

Comment: @AnonJ it suppresses an otherwise spurious blank space between the two `minipage`s; if you don't suppress that space, you'll receive an overfull `\hbox`.

Comment: This I know from the comments. What i wanted to ask is *why* it is achieved by the % character and what other possible uses does this % character potentially have (its usage here I definitely didn't know before). Probably I should have paraphrased my question a little bit differently.

Comment: @Anonj Well `%` causes TeX to ignore everything to its right so, in particular, the space is killed. There are some questions/answers on this site dealing with uses/dangers of `%`; see, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/3954.

Comment: I've got `error “Missing number, treated as zero”` when I used your answer. This worked for me: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56164/5645

Comment: putting ```end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}``` on one line with no space also seems to work (as an alternative to inserting a  ```%``` character.

Comment: I would refer to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56164/91289

Comment: Environment subfigure undefined. \begin{subfigure}

Comment: There can be no line break between the `%` character and the next subfigure. Otherwise the subfigures are not placed side by side.

Comment: *minipage caption overlaps:* you'll probably get it if the graphics take `\linewidth`. So use  use minipages of `0.48\textwidth`, with an `\hfill` in between.

Comment: @bkarpuz What about second one... When ```subfigure``` is not in use?

Comment: It's important to note that \label{} needs to be after \caption{}.

Comment: My two multi-line captions touch each other with the subfigure versions, as if they were the same piece of text. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Posting the version I always make when reading this answer, for my future self:


\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering

\end{minipage}
\end{center}

Comment: Might be one of the longest answers, but one that actually works in many usecases.

Answer (score 190):

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

The PDF documentation with lots of examples can be found here: [subfig.pdf](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig)

Note that you'll see a lot of references to "subfigure" on the net, but that's outdated now.

Here is a small example taken from the documentation

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \subfloat[\centering label 1]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img1} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[\centering label 2]{{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img2} }}%
    \caption{2 Figures side by side}%
    \label{fig:example}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you should run `texdoc subfig`, then you are sure that you'll get the latest version of the documentation.

Comment: What's the `%` after figure for?

Comment: It ensures that Latex does not insert white space at the end of the line, which can have an effect on positioning and line breaks.

Comment: The top voted answer uses `subfigure`. Should I believe that or your answer?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen : The `Subfigure` pack­age is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete: it was su­per­seded by `sub­fig`. Find more documentation here https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig

Comment: The labels are not well positionned when I copy pasted your code... They are at the left side of the images instead of below.

Comment: i've tried this and it doesn't seem to work with overleaf, the figures just arrange one after the other

Comment: How I take off the (a) and (b)???

Comment: Both packages, subfigure and  subfig, are not being maintained anymore. There is no mention here that takes into account that caption package, used in the first answer, is being maintained nowadays. Check https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig, https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure and https://ctan.org/pkg/caption links. Just go for the fist answer, folks.

Answer (score 31):

You could use the `subfigure` package:

```
\begin{figure}
\hfill
\subfigure[Title A]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img1}}
\hfill
\subfigure[Title B]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img2}}
\hfill
\caption{Title for both}
\end{figure}
```

Or try this use the `subfig` package with `\usepackage{subfig}`:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\parbox{5cm}{
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img1}
\caption{First.}
\label{fig:2figsA}}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{img2}
\caption{Second.}
\label{fig:2figsB}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks rekire. But the images are not being displayed.

Comment: You have to change the `img1` and `img2`

Comment: Ya rekire. It does not work for me

Comment: I'm using this code in my master thesis together with this `\usepackage{subfigure}` import.

Comment: Thanks rekire. The above code specified is working for me. But how to put an individual caption for each figure.

Comment: I added a `subfig` example.

Comment: The second example does note make use of the `subfig` package at all!?

Comment: I think it would be better not to recommend using the obsolete package `subfigure`.

Answer (score 15):

Since you didn't tell anything about whether these figures are going to be sub-figures or figures with continued numbering, here is an example that uses the [floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-1}}{%
        \rule{1.6in}{0.9in}   % Just a dummy. Replace with your figure.
      }
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig:dummy-2}}{%
        \rule{1.6in}{0.9in}   % Just a dummy. Replace with your figure.
      }
    \end{floatrow}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to replace the `\rule` commands with the images you want to include. For details please see the package manual.

Comment: I just make an anchor for this solution. thanks :-)