# beamer: How to align two images side by side and to scale them automatically to use whole slide?

Tags: beamer, positioning, scaling

I have two images. How do I align them side by side and scale them so that both of them together occupy the whole horizontal space in a beamer presentation?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inconsistency}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{peer}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{peer-inconsistent}  
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If vertical size do not matter, then you could use

```
\includegraphics[width=<X>\textwidth]{<first image>}%
\includegraphics[width=<1-X>\textwidth]{<second image>}
```

Here `<X>` denotes a number in (0,1), while `<1-X>` denotes its complement in the interval (0,1). Note the `%` to remove any space between the images. For equally-sized images, `<X>`=`<1-X>`=`.5`. Using only `width` as the scaling dimension will scale the height proportionally, maintaining the aspect ratio.

If vertical size *does* matter, you can also specify the `height`.

Comment: why do I get  Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) error? for `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{peer}`

Comment: @user494461: I don't know. You need to provide more context (either in comment, but preferably by editing your original question).

Comment: @user494461: This should work perfectly. Could you check it again. If the issue is still there, please post a full compilable example which causes the issue.

Comment: That works fine for me. However I want to add captions under the images. So I have to use some `figure` environnement for which your solution does not work. I find [minicaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) able to do that in beamer. The only problem is that you have two width: the width of the minifigure and the width of the image in the figure so tweaking is needed.

Comment: +1 for the `%` at the line end. This one gets me again and again.

Comment: @Christoph90: Sure. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 34):

If you want to add captions to it, I suggest:

```
\begin{frame}{Pixelweise Segmentierung}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a.png}
            \caption{Label for a}
            \label{fig:a}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b.png}
            \caption{Label for b}
            \label{fig:b}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Additionally, you might want to add the line

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
```

to prevent the prefix "Figure" ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82460/5645)).

Answer (score 28):

Just use `width=0.5\textwidth` instead of `scale=3`. The `width` option will scale an image to match the given width while keeping the aspect ratio.

To get a little white space between them you may use something like this.

```
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{peer}
   \hfill
   \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{peer-inconsistent}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `columns` enviroment:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Incosistency}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{peer}
        \end{center}
    \column{.5\texwidth}
        \begin{center}
             \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{peer-inconsistent} 
        \end{center}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: This won't scale the images to the required size.

Comment: I had wrongly interpreted the question, my bad.

Comment: There's a small typo. Replace 'texwidth' by 'textwidth' ;-)