# caption images in beamer inside column env

Tags: beamer, presentations, includegraphics

How do i caption these images?

```
\begin{frame}{Einführung 2}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{FiguresAndPictures/AlleAktien-Netflix-Logo.png}\vspace{0.5cm}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/Amazon-Logo.jpg}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/facebook.png}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable MWE that allows others to reproduce the issue (vertical alignment...) you describe. Regarding the captions, you might be interested in [Adding captions to aligned images in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232259/134144)

Comment: the vertical alignment is not that big of an issue, i can delete that part of the code ...

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232259/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with use of `capt-of` package:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % in real document remove option "demo"
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0ex}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1.5ex}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Einführung 2}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{FiguresAndPictures/AlleAktien-Netflix-Logo.png}
        \captionof{figure}{A}

        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/Amazon-Logo.jpg}
        \captionof{figure}{B}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/facebook.png}
        \captionof{figure}{C}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Captions}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure a.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure b.}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure c.}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]