# Problem with a side by side image in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to put two images side by side in the same beamer. I am trying different solutions and I am focusing on this answer [How to align two images side by side and to scale them automatically to use whole slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53869/how-to-align-two-images-side-by-side-and-to-scale-them-automatically-to-use-whol) given by @Martin Thoma.

I am exactly doing the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.65\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
            \label{fig:a}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1.55\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}
            \label{fig:b}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, the picture are still not very well appreciate (a bit small) and they are a bit on the right part of the beamer. I would like to increase a bit the size of the pictures. First, moving them a bit to the left (maybe also a bit upwards) and increase the size. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Erh, what exactly is `width=1.55\textwidth` suppose to do here? I would just use `width=\linewidth`, then it adjusts to the size of the minipage.

Comment: Plus, please complete your example and make it compilable. (`\begin/end{document}` is missing)

Comment: Thank you @daleif . Do you mean changing where I wrote \textwidth put instead \linewidth ? I did it and I changed a bit of the size but they are still in the right part of the beamer. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @daleif I already edited my question with that changes. Thank you!

Comment: we still can not run the example, please use `example-image-a` and -b as in my answer as they are generally available

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for pointing me out. I think I already did it.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to load `graphicx` (`beamer` loads it already) and you don't need `figure` or `minipage`

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}

\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want the image bigger than .5\textwidth you need to bled in to the margins

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Comparison}

\hspace*{-.75cm}%
\includegraphics[width=.53\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.53\textwidth]{example-image-b.png}%
\hspace*{-.75cm}%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle. I tried that solution but the images appears really small and when I increase the width=. to something greater they just put one below to another and I would like to have them side by side

Comment: @OgeiD if you want them side by side you can't have them much bigger than .47 textwidth.  If you want to bleed in to the margin you could make them a big bigger, see update

Comment: Thank you for the uptade @David Carlisle. When I do that, they are still very small and when I increase a bit the textwidth they appears one below to another. I am not sure if it is a problem of the images but they seem ok when I open them. They are big.

Comment: @OgeiD do your images have a lot of white space? if you do `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=...]{...}}` is the box tight round the image? you might want to use an image editor to clip the image to the real size

Comment: In principle, there is not a lot of white space but I should check that carefully

Comment: @OgeiD so now your example uses the same images as this answer I can not guess what issue you still have, you can not make the images any bigger and have them fit on a line,