# Inserting subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm trying to insert a nested figure using the environment subfigure following the example in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats

I added the following extra packages:
`\usepackage{subfigure}`,
`\usepackage{caption}` and 
`\usepackage{subcaption}`.

this is my MWE:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}%[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SR4000}
            \caption{SwissRanger by MESA}
            \label{fig:SRl}
    \end{subfigure}%
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}%[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{D-Imager}
            \caption{D-Imager by Panasonic}
            \label{fig:D-Imager}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{TOF depth cameras}\label{fig:TOF}
\end{figure}
```

but I am getting the following error

```
! Use of \@subfloat doesn't match its definition. \reserved@c
->\@subfloat {
                          sub\@captype }[\@empty {\@empty }][{\@empty }] 
l.64                 \centering
```

line 64 here is:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SR4000}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `subfigure` and `subcaption` both. Also, `subfigure` is obsolete. Newer one is `subfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}            
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{SwissRanger by MESA}
            \label{fig:SRl}
    \end{subfigure}%
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{D-Imager by Panasonic}
            \label{fig:D-Imager}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{TOF depth cameras}\label{fig:TOF}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked with the packages you mentioned, but I had to add the {caption} package, but then when I compile i get an error that I cant find, it just tells me there are one error

'
 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 45)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 8   Bad Boxes: 8'

Comment: And the error is `
! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption)                with the subfig package.`