# **"No counter 'subfigure@save defined."** -subfig error

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I have used `subfig` package to compile the following code. The code was running fine in linux machine (That too without loading the 'subfig' package). Now in Windows machine, I am having error message:

```
No counter 'subfigure@save defined.
```

Code:

```
\usepackage{multicol}    
\usepackage{dcolumn}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{subcaption}     
\usepackage{float}    
\usepackage{subfig}    
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}    
\centering    
\subfloat[]{\label{mathm1a}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{1}}   
\end{minipage}%   
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}   
\centering    
\subfloat[]{\label{1}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{2}}     
\end{minipage}\par\medskip   
\centering    
\subfloat[]{\label{2}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{3}}   
\caption[Free-wake model] model}   
\label{fig:main}   
\end{figure}
```

I tried shifting the placement of `subcaption` package and `subfig` to no use. Any help on what the error means and why I am getting it is acknowledged gratefully.

Comment: You shouldn't mix the use of [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) and [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption). Use one or the other. It seems like, in your case, you're using the interface of `subfig`, so drop `subcaption`.

Comment: Thanks Werner. As my tex document was working fine with subcaption, I used them liberally in the whole document. Now when I removed subcaption, I got lot more errors. Probably have to modify the whole document if the two package are not compatible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which solution did you end up with to this problem? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: This answer helped me to solve this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83665/61609

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is old, but I have the same problem today and i find the solution reviewing the code that Lyx generate when the text has subfigure with caption

```
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
\PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
```

Comment: this doesn't work! does anyone have a solution t this problem?

Comment: in my case it was caused by a conflict between subcaption and subfigure packages. I removed subcaption and it worked!