# Using subfig in one chapter and subcaption in the other

Tags: subfloats

I'm combining my papers into a thesis, and apparently I used subfigures using the `subfig` package in one paper and `subcaption` in another. This was a bad idea as the packages clash and generally can't be used together, e.g. 
[**"No counter 'subfigure@save defined."** -subfig error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210208/no-counter-subfiguresave-defined-subfig-error)

I was wondering, since I'm using each exclusively in a separate chapter, is there any way to load the package selectively per chapter, or do I need to change all subfigures to be of the same package?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: here's how I solved it. It might not be elegant but it works. I'm adding it to the question and not as a solution since a more elegant solution is always welcome.

1. I disabled the loading of the `subfig` package.
2. I wrote the `subfig` command as follows:

`\newcommand{\subfloat}[3][LABEL]{% 
   \begin{subfigure}{#3\textwidth}%
     #2%
     \caption{#1}%
   \end{subfigure}% 
}`

so that now the call to `\subfig[caption]{content}{number}` translates to a subfigure. The third argument is due to the fact that I usually place `includegraphics` commands whose widths are controlled using the `includegraphics` command in the `subfloat` case, whereas in `subfigure` it's controlled via the `subfigure` wrapper. So I needed to manually remove the width definition and put it as an external argument.