# Dealing with figures in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have two figures I want them to be side-by-side, and I have two issues:

1) How to make both figures have the same size? I know that dimensions are not the same for both figures, but how can I make them the same? (both figures are in pdf format)

2) I want to include one caption for both figures.. say, Figure 1, but underneath the figure on the left side I want to put (a), and underneath the figure on right side I want to put (b).. so we have figure 1(a) and Figure 1(b).

This is ehat I have so far:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\mbox{\subfigure{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure1_a.pdf}
\quad
\subfigure{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure1_b.pdf} }}}
\caption{caption for figure 1}
\label{fig12}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This might habe been answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37581/21591

Comment: Thanks, but how can i resize both figures to be the same?

Comment: use height=5cm instead of scale=...

Comment: I tried it, but still getting different heights...

Comment: If you are getting different heights, it means that the bounding boxes aren't tight (white space above/below what you consider to be the figure). Where do the figures come from?

Comment: Any question about the `figure` environment is about dealing with figures. Your question is more specific. It would be nice if you could reflect that in the title. Also it would be nice if you could turn your code into a minimum working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `graphicx` you can set the `width` of the figure.

So you should do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Same width

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-16x10}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-10x16}
\vspace{1cm}

Same height

\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
     \hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-16x10}\hspace*{\fill}\par
     \hspace*{\fill}Caption for first\hspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
    \hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-10x16}\hspace*{\fill}\par
     \hspace*{\fill}Caption for second\hspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{1cm}

Same height and width (ick!)

\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=2cm]{example-image-16x10}
\includegraphics[height=3cm,width=2cm]{example-image-10x16}

\end{document}
```

[image]