# Caption issue when placing figure side by side

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, minipage

I placed 2 figures side by side using the `minipage` method from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/14127), and the figures look perfectly fine. However, the caption of the right figure stick out into the margin, why is that and how can I fix it?

[image]

My code is like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.6cm]{figure1.png}
    \caption{Caption for figure 1.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.6cm]{figure2.png}
    \caption{Caption for figure 2, but longer.}
    \label{fig:fig2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the `subcaption` package along with a subfigure?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: What you have added is not a minimal example: we don't know the class and possible tweaks to the page setup.

Comment: @egreg, OK, I see what you mean now. The problem is the template package provided by the publisher. I cannot reproduce the issue with the standard `graphicx` package either. I need to look into the template or maybe it simply doesn't allow me to put them side by side.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the simplest method to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % [demo] is just for the example
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=4cm]{a}
\caption{A not so wide caption}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=4cm]{a}
\caption{A caption that should be wider than the figure, but so wide that it should wrap}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here it's assumed that the two pictures have the same height, so that correct alignment is obtained for the captions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain which line of code makes it to wrap around? I couldn't tell any difference between my code and yours, except I set my image width to absolute value using `width=6cm`, and yours is `width=.8\textwidth`.

Comment: @LWZ I've used the standard methods. Without seeing your code I can't say more. Using an absolute value might create overfull boxes, though: if 6cm is more than `.45\textwidth` the figure can't be accommodated.

Comment: This is strange. I uploaded my code. I also tried using `width=.8\textwidth` and it still has the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you go for the `subcaption` package, since this is the purpose of it, and do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{MuscularTissue3_1}
            \caption{Skeletal}
        \label{fig:SkeletalTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{MuscularTissue3_2}
            \caption{Cardiac}
        \label{fig:CardiacTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two Types of Muscular Tissue}
    \label{fig:MuscularTissue}
\end{figure}

If you want to reference the first figure (Figure~\ref{fig:SkeletalTissue}), if you want the second (Figure~\ref{fig:CardiacTissue}).  If you want to reference both (Figure~\ref{fig:MuscularTissue}


\end{document}
```

I don't have your figures, so I just put some of mine.   The output would be something like this:

[image]

For more information, please refer to the `subfigure` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However in my case I do have two separate figures, and the only reason I put them side by side is to save space. They do not have a common caption.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this problem myself and found the solution I think:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % [demo] is just for the example
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
 \captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth} % Choose 0.45 to leave some space between captions
 \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} % Choose 0.49 to prevent minipages stacking
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{a} % Choose smaller than 1 to have space between figures
  \captionof{figure}{Caption text for figure 1 and it is quite long.}\label{fig:figure1}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} % Choose 0.49 to prevent minipages stacking
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{a} % Choose smaller than 1 to have space between figures
  \captionof{figure}{Caption text for figure 2 and it is quite long.}\label{fig:figure2}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Summary: change \caption{caption text} to \captionof{figure}{caption text} and set the width using the 'caption' package.

Regards,

Ernst Jan