# Subfigure caption as normal caption

Tags: floats

I'm trying give the reference to the subfigure, but I want that instead of figure number as, 1a and 1b, I want them to be 1, 2 etc. and in sync with normal figure number. Can anyone give any insight to that?

Comment: We can give lots of insight, when you provide us with your setup via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). It would help us understand the requirements in terms of your referencing and speed up the process of getting you answers.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want subfigures at all, but something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111513/586 http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/586

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `floatrow` package is done for that. It has an eponymous environment that takes an argument, the number of figures in a row (default is 2) and  figures are inserted in the form: `\ffigbox{image}{caption title+label}`. Similarly there is a `\ttabbox` command for tables. If you want subfigures, there is a `subfloatrow` environment. The package cooperates with the `caption` package, and it supports sideways captions.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{sendak}}
{\caption{Where Wild Things are}
\label{fig:Maurice}}

\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{AliceSteadman}}
{\caption{Ralph}
\label{fig:Wabbit}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]