# Vertically center two side by side figures, leaving captions on the same line

Tags: floats, positioning

I would like to place two independent figures (no subfigures) besides each other. Each figure should have its own caption. [This approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/18029) uses two `minipage`s inside a `figure` environment and is nearly what I'm looking for. But my figures don't have the same height, so I want to center them vertically, whereas the captions should stay on the same line.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.8\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This shows how the output looks vs. how I would like it to look:

[image: how it should look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy solution using the `floatrow` package, which I find most satisfactory, so I'm going to accept this as the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \floatsetup{heightadjust=all, valign=c}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox{%
      \rule{3cm}{6cm}% replace with figure
    }{%
      \captionof{figure}{A figure}%
      \label{fig:test1}%
    }
    \ffigbox{%
      \rule{3cm}{3cm}% replace with figure
    }{%
      \captionof{figure}{Another figure}%
      \label{fig:test2}%
    }
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The vertical alignment can be modified simply by changing the `valign` setting with `\floatsetup`. You can also set this globally by moving the respective line into your preamble.

The `rawfloats` package option is important in order not to break existing standard floats.

## Result

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

A layman's solution is to use four `minipage`s - two for figures and two for `captionof`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\par
\medskip
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure Another figure Another figure Another figure Another figure Another figure Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, the captions will be horizontally centered only if I set their respective `minipage`s' width to `.5\textwidth` as well (this is due to the `\hfill`). In addition, the vertical space between figure 1 and its caption looks too small compared to a normal figure.

Answer (score 1):

I constructed `\figstrut` which takes two argument.

- ## 1: Height of object
- ## 2: Height of highest object

It creates a `\vrule` to centre the object with respect to a certain height. In the example the highest object is the other figure with `.8\linewidth` and the object to centre is `.4\linewidth` high. Hence we need

```
\figstrut{.4\linewidth}{.8\linewidth}
```

to adjust the line to the correct height.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\figstrut[2]{
  % #1: Height of object
  % #2: Height of highest object
  \dimen0=#1%
  \advance\dimen0 by -#2%
  \divide\dimen0 by -2%
  \dimen1=#1%
  \advance\dimen1 by \dimen0%
  \vrule height \dimen1 depth \dimen0 width 0pt\relax%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.8\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \figstrut{.4\linewidth}{.8\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Some of my figures are `TikZ` pictures, though, in which case it's not that easy to find the exact height parameters for your `\figstrut` command. I would prefer some automatic solution, but as a workaround, this is certainly ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a box to save the heighest object. Using height and depth of this box the other object is set in a vertical centered `minipage` of the same totalheight:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\sbox\mybox{%
  \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth, height=.4\linewidth]{image1}
}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \usebox\mybox
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox\relax][c]{\linewidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=.4\linewidth]{image1}
  \end{minipage}%
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\linewidth` inside a `minipage` means the width of the `minipage`.