# How can I arrange multiple figures in rows of 3 in a two-column document?

Tags: floats, two-column

I have 8 figures, which need to included in a two-column style paper. The figures should be added at the top of the corresponding page, three figures in each row (figure alignment is not as the two-column style).

i.e.:

```
fig1:   fig2:    fig3:

fig4:   fig5:    fig6:
```

Each figure should not start with `(a)`... `(b)`...... likewise.

Can anybody tell how to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: See this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side

Comment: You can also arrange them using a tabular.  Unlike captions (which are used by hyperref and the toc) subcaptions are just text.

Comment: If you want to place multiple figures with captions into a single float, use \capstart from hypcap at the beginning, and either add multiple captions or use \refstepcounter{figure} and \label{fig:} where you write the captions.

Comment: My apologies.  I hit the down vote button in error and didn't notice until too late.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) to produce sub-elements inside a float:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,subcaption}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{fig\arabic{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Fig1}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Fig2}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Fig3}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

  \bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{Fig4}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Fig5}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Fig6}[.3\linewidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Note that column-spanning floats in `twocolumn` mode will always follow the page where you put the `figure*` environment. If you want it on a different page, you need to adjust the placement accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

One simple approach with the `multicol` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,multicol}
\begin{document}
%\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}\par\caption{caption}
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\par\caption{caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}\par\caption{caption}
\end{multicols}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works with hyperref and \listoffigures, but not hypcap.

Comment: @JohnKormy I disagree. As far I can see, the MWE works perfectly  in TeXLive 2013 with `hypcap` also, using `evince` as pdf viewer. Try using this package after `hyperref` and one `\capstart` for each each `\includegraphics` (six commands), just *before* of each image.

Comment: Eek!  All this time I've been typing \startcap instead of \capstart!  It appears I just re-invented the wheel for no reason.

Comment: @Fran: It works brilliantly, but the problem is I am not able to add labels to my subfigures. How do I do that?

Comment: @ThePredator I see no problem with `\caption{... \label{x}}`,  `\caption{... \label{y}}` ....  and  then  make  the cross-reference with `\ref{x}`  as `\ref{y}`, just a  with floats with only one figure.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was a little more complicated than I thought.  The hard part was getting the links go to the top of the images.

I should mention that the hyperlinks to figures 1-3 all actually link to figure 3.  But so long as they are all on the same level, it doesn't matter.  If you want to set a label, do it after the corresponding \figtarget.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdftoolbar=true,pdfpagemode=UseNone,pdfstartview=FitH,
  colorlinks=true,extension=}

\newcounter{multifig}

% uased to synchronize \figtarget to \figcaption
\newcommand{\multifig}{\setcounter{multifig}{\thefigure}}

% location of hyperlink target (place \label after)
\newcommand{\figtarget}{\refstepcounter{figure}}

% corresponding caption
\newcommand{\figcaption}[1]% #1 = text
{\stepcounter{multifig}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\string\numberline {\arabic{multifig}}{\ignorespaces #1}}
Figure \arabic{multifig}: #1}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure*}[t]
\multifig% better safe than sorry
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\figtarget & \figtarget & \figtarget \\
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-b} \\
\figcaption{first} & \figcaption{second} & \figcaption{third} \\
\figtarget & \figtarget & \figtarget \\
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image} &
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-b} \\
\figcaption{fourth} & \figcaption{fifth} & \figcaption{sixth}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}
\caption{normal}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

[image: multifig]

Intead of a tabular, one could put each image/caption into a separate parbox and pack them together with \hfill or \hfil.