# How to arrange 8 figures, with subcaptions, in a 3-row form

Tags: graphics, subfloats

[image]

I want to figure out how to make an arrangement of eight figures into a compact form as shown in the picture. Could some give a hand?

Comment: you could use subfloats as explained here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Searching in this site will show you, that you can use some answers on similar questions ...

Comment: one of these examples, would be [How can I arrange multiple figures in rows of 3 in a two-column document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186615/how-can-i-arrange-multiple-figures-in-rows-of-3-in-a-two-column-document)

Comment: I wonder why people have such a hard time putting images on a page? Is it really that hard to transform a *How can i put 4 by 2 images on a page?* answer to 3 by 3 or 3 by 4?

Comment: Which LaTeX document class do you use? Not all subfigure-related packages are compatible with all document classes?

Comment: the document class is \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: I refer to ' How can I arrange multiple figures in rows of 3 in a two-column document? , still I found a problem. in that example, all the subfigure started with fig x:, in my case, i wished it to be (a)(b)..., i was wondering how to change that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning in a comment which document class you use -- `IEEEtran`, with the option `conference`. Since this document class uses a two-column layout, the first and most important measure to take is to employ a `figure*` environment, which takes up the width of both columns, instead of a "normal" `figure` environment.

To position the eight subfigures along with their `\caption`s within the `figure*` environment, I suggest you load the `subcaption` package and use that package's `subfigure` environment. In the following code, the amount of whitespace between the graphs in the third row is set to be same as it is in the first two rows, viz., `0.05\textwidth`. If you want more horizontal separation between the graphis in the final row, simply increase the value of the argument of next-to-last `\hspace*` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,demo]{IEEEtran}  % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
% first row: 3 subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fa}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fb}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_b}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fc}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_c}
\end{subfigure}

% 2nd row: 3 more subfigures
\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fd}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_d}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fe}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_e}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ff}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_f}
\end{subfigure}

% 3rd row: just 2 subfigures, centered
\bigskip
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fg}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_g}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fh}
   \caption{xxx} \label{fig:x_h}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}

\caption{yyy}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```