# undefined control sequence for \subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, include

using TeXShop in OS X Maverick, a simple subfigure script is returning "undefined control sequence". Although I can bypass it and still generate the image-included pdf by typing "s" to "ignore all" (of the warnings), I would still like to know the cause and fix for this. Thanks!

The sample script is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htdp]
  \begin{center}
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig1}}
    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig2}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add `\usepackage{subfigure}` to the preamble. Notice, however, that this package is obsolete; you should use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead and change to the syntax for those packages.

Comment: Fixed it with the preamble! Thanks! Can you give a quick example of the new syntax?

Comment: Refer to the documentation for the packages. Also, there are plenty of examples in the site of the syntax for both packages.

Comment: For an example with `subcaption`, see the first code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/3954.