# Two figure side-by-side in a single column of tikzposter?

Tags: floats, tikzposter

How to put two figures (different sizes) side by side in a single block in tikzposter?

Is there a neat way of using?

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure]
\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{image}
\end{tikzfigure}
```

My code is:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure1]
\includegraphics[height = 10cm]{figure1}
\end{tikzfigure}
\hfill
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure2]
\includegraphics[height = 10cm]{figure2}
\end{tikzfigure}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\noindent
```

but the pictures a misaligned (vertically). I tried this suggestion:
[LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side)
but it did not work properly. Normally I use

```
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
```

environment, but it does not work with *tikzfigure*.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{A Title}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure1]
  \includegraphics[height = 10cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure2]
  \includegraphics[height = 10cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You probably might want to control the figures' width instead of their height, as in

```
\includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{image}
```

and using the optional argument for `minipage`, you can adjust vertical alignment; for example, using `b` (bottom alignment):

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{A Title}{%
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure1]
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,height=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure2]
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,height=10cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect (as usual)!! Thanks! I put incorrectly the "\hfill" and it causes the picture misaligned.

Comment: @Gonzalo Is there a way to set the distance between the two figures?

Answer (score 2):

```
\column{0.5}
\block{A figure}
 {
        \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{thankyoupostit.png}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{thankyoupostit.png}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{thankyoupostit.png}
        \end{tikzfigure}
  }
```

We can put as many as figures very simply as done in above code snippet. But for this the **total width requirement for images should be less than or equal to the size of column**.