# What is wrong in this arithmetic with looping?

Tags: beamer, loops

I want to loop 4x2 figures on many pages in `beamer`. 
The page number setting fails `page=\numexp \ii * 2 \relax`. 
Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                          
\usepackage{subcaption} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/13173

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \foreach \ii in {1,...,4}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering% not \center!
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.altman.1}.pdf}
      \caption{Image \ii.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2, page=\numexp \ii * 2 \relax]{{Rplots.bland.altman.1}.pdf}
      \caption{Image \ii.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output does not make sense to me; trying to solve it by `\newcounter{ii}` does not help.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GPT@page ->\numexp 
                    \ii * 2 \relax 
l.23 \end{frame}
```

Output with `\the\numexp ...`

```
...
? 
! You can't use `the character 1' after \the.
\ii ->1

l.23 \end{frame}

? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.23 \end{frame}

? 
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   *
l.23 \end{frame}

? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.23 \end{frame}
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: `\includegraphics[scale=0.2, page=\the\numexpr \ii * 2 \relax]{{Rplots.bland.altman.1}.pdf}`  2 mistakes: 1) `\numexpr`, not `\numexp` and 2) you need `\the\numexpr` in order to make it digestible by something looking for  a string.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It seems to work! Can the images made smaller during the process? - - They are very big for LaTeX.

Comment: It's called `\numexpr`, not `\numexp`, and it has to resolve to a number, so use `page=\number\numexpr\ii*2` or `page=\the\numexpr\ii*2`.

Comment: You control the size of the images by way of the `scale=` parameter.  Perhaps using `\width=` or `height=` would work better for you, instead of `scale=`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can the physical size too be controlled? My images are just too big in MBs.

Comment: To reduce the file size, you literally have to save the images in a smaller (reduced resolution) format before including them in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I converted from `beamer` to `article`, just so that I could use `demo` mode of `graphicx`.  But there were two issues, as I said in my comment:

1. `\numexpr`, not `\numexp` is the proper syntax, and
2. you need `\the\numexpr` in order to make it digestible by something looking for a string. (to see this, try outputting `\numexpr 0\relax` in a document versus `\the\numexpr 0\relax`)

As the OP noted, setting the `subfigure` width to `0.45\textwidth` allows two figures per row.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}%{beamer}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor,subcaption}                                                            

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \foreach \ii in {1,...,4}{
    \begin{figure}
    \centering% not \center!
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.altman.1}.pdf}
      \caption{Image \ii.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2, page=\the\numexpr \ii * 2 \relax]{{Rplots.bland.altman.1}.pdf}
      \caption{Image \ii.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    }
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Images go side by side by changing textwidth to 0.45.