# how to use a condition given a value of loop?

Tags: macros

I want to know how can I write a lopp in order to put some graphs on my document with a different caption. I have n graphs with a variable name, i.e. "activos_t" with the label "Activos Totales" & "pasivos_t" with the label "Pasivos Totales". I want the caption to be different for each variable name contained in the following loop

```
\foreach \w in {activos_t,pasivos_t}{

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering 
\caption{"label"}
\label{fig:Figura }
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{C:/Users/G15185/Desktop/ProyectoLATEXentregable/\w.png}
\end{figure}
}
```

Does anybody know how can I use an "if else" statement or any other condition to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe this question is of some help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339342/what-is-wrong-in-this-arithmetic-with-looping

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\w` in the `\caption`.  However, because it contains an underscore, you can't typeset it as is outside of math mode.  So instead, I `\detokenize` it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \w in {activos_t,pasivos_t}{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering 
\caption{\detokenize\expandafter{\w} Totales}
\label{fig:Figura }
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{C:/Users/G15185/Desktop/ProyectoLATEXentregable/\w.png}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get the `\w` values capitalized in the `\caption`, one must expand and save the `\detokenize` result and pass it to `\titlecap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,titlecaps}
\begin{document}
\foreach \w in {activos_t,pasivos_t}{
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\xdef\tmp{\detokenize\expandafter{\w} totales}
\expandafter\caption\expandafter{\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\tmp}}
\label{fig:Figura }
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{C:/Users/G15185/Desktop/ProyectoLATEXentregable/\w.png}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]