# How to Get Two Plots in Float to be side by side and proportional?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, minipage, calculations, adjustbox

I am using the following code to get two figures side by side. The code (MWE) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}  
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0.1,{ln(0.1)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5,{ln(5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{ln(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{ln(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
   \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) |- (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) -- (Up-mid2);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Risk Aversion}\label{RA}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5.5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0,{(0)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5.5,{(5.5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[align=right,font=\scriptsize,xshift=-40pt]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)=$\\$=u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Risk Neutrality}\label{RN}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is this one:

[image]

Though the result does not look bad, I would like the plots to be the exact same size; that is, the same length of the axes, same font size, and so on. However, with my code I get that the plot in the right-hand side is slightly larger that the one in the left. I want to avoid that. Does anybody know how to achieve that? I am afraid I may need to adjust the axes of the figures, but whatever I try, I deliberately fail. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove all the nested `figure`, `adjustbox` and `minipage` stuff. Then scale down the larger plot using the `xscale` and `yscale` options of tikz (or scale up the smaller plot, if you prefer). For the x-axis, you can compute the factor since the domain is given; it is 5/5.5=0.90909.... For the y-axis, I chose the practical approach and just modified it until it looked the same. So we have to add

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[...,xscale=0.90909,yscale=0.75]
```

in the second plot.

The advantage of this kind of scaling over `\adjustbox` is that just the coordinate system is scaled but not fonts and line widths.

Regarding your second question of how to place two figures side by side, may I refer you to [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/110998), [LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/110998) and many similar posts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex}]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0.1,{ln(0.1)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5,{ln(5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{ln(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{ln(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
   \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) |- (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) -- (Up-mid2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5.5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex},xscale=0.90909,yscale=0.75]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0,{(0)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5.5,{(5.5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[align=right,font=\scriptsize,xshift=-40pt]{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)=$\\$=u(px+(1-p)y)$} cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is the wrapper to fit the plots, including captions, on an article page. I additionally use the trick to remove the width of the long labels using `\llap{...}` such that the labels stick into the margin and the other figure, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\newcommand\commonscalefactor{0.64}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-1em}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex},scale=\commonscalefactor]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0.1,{ln(0.1)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5,{ln(5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{ln(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{ln(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{ln(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
   \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]
       {\llap{$u(px+(1-p)y)$}} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) |- (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{\llap{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)$}} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up-mid) -- (Up-mid2);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
  \caption{Risk Aversion}\label{RA}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{2em}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-1em}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[my plot/.style={thick, smooth, samples=100, domain=0.1:5.5}, my grid/.style={densely dotted,opacity=0.5, every node/.style={black,opacity=1}}, my axis/.style={latex-latex},xscale=0.90909*\commonscalefactor,yscale=0.75*\commonscalefactor]
    \draw[my plot, color=black] (0,0) plot (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (start plot) at (0,{(0)});
    \coordinate (end plot) at (5.5,{(5.5)});
    \draw[my axis] ([shift={(-0.5cm,0.5cm)}]start plot |- end plot) node[above] {$u(\cdot)$} |- node[coordinate](origin){} ([shift={(0.5cm,-0.5cm)}]start plot -| end plot) node[right] {$\cdot$};
    \def\x{0.5}\def\y{4}\def\p{0.55}
    \coordinate (Ux) at (\x,{(\x)});
    \coordinate (Uy) at (\y,{(\y)});
    \coordinate (Up) at ({\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y},{(\p*\x+(1-\p)*\y)});
    \draw (Ux) -- coordinate[pos=1-\p] (Up-mid) (Uy);
    \path let \p1=(Up-mid), \n1={pow(e,\y1*0.03514)} in (28.4576*\n1,\y1) coordinate (Up-mid2);
    \draw[my grid] (Ux) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$x$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(x)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Uy) |- node[below,font=\scriptsize]{$y$} (origin) |- node[left,font=\scriptsize]{$u(y)$} cycle;
    \draw[my grid] (Up) |- node[below, yshift=2.25pt, font=\scriptsize]{$px+(1-p)y$} (origin) |- node[align=right,font=\scriptsize,xshift=-0.5em]{\llap{$pu(x)+(1-p)u(y)=$}\\\llap{$=u(px+(1-p)y)$}} cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \caption{Risk Neutrality}\label{RN}
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am willing to accept your answer as the answer I was looking for. Nonetheless, this fits in the document you create because you define a tiny page margin os 2mm. However, I am working with standard article margins. Therefore, the figures do not currently fit side by side with the code you provided: they are side by side but they exceed the line width. Also, I am numbering the figures and so on; so I need to keep the figure stuff. When adding the figure stuff, the second figure jumps below the first one. Maybe you could slightly change your answer to accommodate this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Héctor I have added a note on how to put the figures side by side with captions. In one previous posting they are handled as separate figures, in the other one as subfigures of a common figure. Regarding size: Nothing prevents you from additionally scaling both figures by the same factor. If you add `scale=0.5` in the first figure and multiply the scaling factors of the second one also by 0.5, they will only take half the space.

Comment: Marked as accepted. Your code and your comments were enough to get exactly the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: @Héctor I've added a complete version. The `\llap` command may be useful to handle the long labels.