# Discussion on several options for the document

Tags: koma-script, printing, options, questionnaire

I have the boon and bane of the freedom on choosing between several options, sometimes just for the printed version of my generated document. As I already googled around, there are many opposed recommendations and I just want to hear what and why you would prefer one over the other option. I hope you are patient enough to discuss with a newbie on these options.

EDIT1: Thank you very much for the already valueable und useful hints! I updated the code and erased solved problems or changed it according to the comments. I will have a look to implement the rest of the comments asap.

EDIT2: I guess the rest of the questions is depending on your personal decision and I edited the final MWE for the solved issues. As suggested I opened a new question regarding the problem with the provided solution not compiling on my setup.

Here are the options I am talking about, used in an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=flat,oneside]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead*{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{section}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\KOMAoptions{
    captions=tableheading,
    headsepline=true,
    markcase=upper}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\mbox{e.\,g.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Eg}{\mbox{E.\,g.}\xspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.5cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
%\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[
  pdftoolbar = false,

  pdfmenubar = false, 
  pdftitle   = mwe,
  pdfauthor  = {author},
  colorlinks,
  allcolors =  {blue},
  bookmarks         = true,
  bookmarksopen     = true, 
  bookmarksnumbered = true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{leer}
\section{Chapter one} \label{sec:ChapterOne}
This text shows the current options that I have used for the printed version of my document. What and why would you change something? 
\begin{itemize}
\item Referencing in blue. \Eg: Chapter one on page \ref{sec:ChapterOne}
\item In-text math mode I use tfrac or nicefrac like this $\tfrac{1}{2}$ or this $\nicefrac{1}{2}$ and dfrac in the stand-alone equations. Or is sfrac of the xfrac package the way to go? $\sfrac{1}{2}$. What is the difference?
\item Different fonts for print-out and digital copy? \Eg helvet for pdf for no serifs?
\end{itemize}
\newpage
Thats what the pagestyle I have choosed looks like, but there is a warning about fancyhdr, how to produce the same output with KOMA?

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \null\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Example A}\label{fig:a}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{Example B}\label{fig:b}
    \end{minipage}   
    \hfill\null   
\caption{Two figures with subcaption and minipage}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}

Comment: To get more out of the build in head- and footline options from KOMA-script you could opt for `scrlayer-scrpage` (instead of using `fancyhdr`).

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: If you're loading `mathtools`, it loads `amsmath` by default, so there's no need to load it twice. And I think `subfigure` is deprecated, use `subcaption` or `subfig` packages instead. There's plenty of questions here regarding including images side by side.

Comment: @Johannes_B The questions are in the code. I was confused for a bit too.

Comment: Regarding your subfigures, see the answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/117534

Comment: You should not use only `[!h]` for the figureplacement. It gets replaced by `[!ht]` (emitting a warning) and might result in bad placement (at the end of the document or chapter)! You could use `[!htbp]` which results in the same as `[!ht]` most of the time.

Comment: I personally dislike the uppercase headline. For e.g. you should use the stuff you defined in your `\eg`-command (half blank `\,`).

Comment: If you use serif font and the default Computer Modern, you should include `\usepackage{lmodern}` which looks slightly better (Computer Modern can have a pixelated look). For multiple cites some may use `[1, 2]`, which is supported by `biblatex` and the like.

Comment: The warning about thumbnails is caused by your usage of `\usepackage{thumbpdf}`. Do you really need that package? If so, read the documentation how to use it correctly.

Comment: Also: If you use the same optional argument for all of your figures (and/or tables), you can set the default placement with: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{!htbp}\makeatother`, for tables, replace `\fps@figure` with `\fps@table`.

Comment: Do you want to use chapters with pagestyle `plain` on chapter pages? Then have a look at documentclass `scrreprt` or `scrbook`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the setup of your head- and footline with `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead*{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{section}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading,
    headsepline=true,
    markcase=upper}
```

Use `\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}` instead of your `\thispagestyle{leer}`.

Embedded in your complete code (might not be the most recent version of your MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=flat,oneside]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead*{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{section}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\KOMAoptions{
    captions=tableheading,
    headsepline=true,
    markcase=upper}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\eg}{\mbox{e.\,g.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Eg}{\mbox{E.\,g.}\xspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.5cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
%\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
%\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[%
  pdftoolbar = false,
  pdfmenubar = false, 
  pdftitle   = mwe,
  pdfauthor  = {author},
  colorlinks,
  allcolors =  {blue},
  bookmarks         = true,
  bookmarksopen     = true, 
  bookmarksnumbered = true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\section{Chapter one} \label{sec:ChapterOne}
This text shows the current options that I have used for the printed version of my document. What and why you would change something? 
\begin{itemize}
\item Referencing in blue. \Eg: Chapter one on page \ref{sec:ChapterOne}
\item In-text math mode I use tfrac or nicefrac like this $\tfrac{1}{2}$ or this $\nicefrac{1}{2}$ and dfrac in the stand-alone equations. Or is sfrac of the xfrac package the way to go? $\sfrac{1}{2}$. What is the difference?
\item Different fonts for print-out and digital copy? \Eg helvet for pdf for no serifs?
\end{itemize}
\newpage
Thats what the pagestyle I have choosed looks like, but there is a warning about fancyhdr, how to produce the same output with KOMA? There is also a warning about no thumbnail data, how to handle this one?


\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \null\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Example A}\label{fig:a}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{Example B}\label{fig:b}
    \end{minipage}   
    \hfill\null   
\caption{Two figures with subcaption and minipage}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this code! Sadly I can´t compile it, the `\ofoot*{\pagemark}` seems to be the problem.

Comment: @NN123 See the edit (it doesn't change anything, but uses the rest of your code).

Comment: thank you again, also for the patience, I´m still getting the same error, I should have provided it earlier I guess: Missing \begin{document}. \ofoot*{\pagemark

Comment: @NN123 Please edit your question providing the code you are using to include my `scrlayer-scrpage` setup (perhaps as a new MCE below the existing one) or ask a new question. The complete example in my answer does compile without any errors.

Comment: I am using your code, copy & paste, still get this error, also tried it with an online compiler resulting in the same error :-( But these online compilers may be not the best solution to try it out. I may have a problem with my TeXStudio or MikTex not beeing up to date or a faulty installation. I will try to figure it out, thank you for all these comments and the provided solution, have a nice day :-)

Comment: That's pretty strange. You might ask a new question on this (perhaps somebody can help you out).

Comment: It was due to an really outdated installation on my site and on the online compiler, your solution works fine, thank you

Comment: @Skillmon You could use `\clearpairofstyles` to clear page header and footer. Package `scrlayer-scrpage` sets pagestyle `scrheadings` automatically. So I would use: `\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage} \clearpairofpagestyles \ihead{\headmark} \ofoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}`. The option `captions=tableheading` could be added to the class options.

Comment: @esdd The option `captions=tableheading` was set with `\KOMAoptions` in NN123's question. I think my more verbose solution is better as it might be easier to modify it for somebody with not much experience with KOMA. In addition I don't see any drawbacks in using `\KOMAoptions` instead of package and class options (except that it takes more letters of input).

Comment: For `captions=tableheading` there is really no difference. But there are other options like `fontsize` that require an explicit recalculation of typearea to get the same layout as if it was a class option.

Comment: @esdd true, but your point regarding `fontsize` is invalid *here* because of the usage of `geometry`, which doesn't use KOMA's `typearea` as far as I know. Still you're right, there are options which should be class options and not being declared late.