# Gap between two side by side images

Tags: graphics, report

Related to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side). How to reduce the default gap between the two side by side images ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which gap? There is no gap? Where is the MWE that shows the gap?

Comment: @Johannes_B, if you go to the hyperlink and check the first answer, between the two images in the output there's, of course, a gap, a distance. I just want to know how to reduce it.

Comment: In one sense there is no gap, in that there is no gap between the `subfigure`/`minipage` environments. But the images inside those environments are much narrower than the width of the environment, so there is a gap between the images. So in that sense there is no default gap, it depends on how large your images are compared to the `minipage`/`subfigure` they're in, and also any space between the `minipage`s`/`subfigure`s.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thank you for the explanation. The caption of one of the images runs to the next line. So I thought, if there's a way I can bring say that image bit closer the other, I can still keep the caption on one line. Maybe my question above wasn't clear .

Comment: If that was what you were asking about it was utterly *unclear*. The width available for the caption is determined by the width of the `subfigure`/`minipage`, so make one `subfigure` a bit wider, the other narrower by the same amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no gap between images. The gap is due to the size of each image inside every subfigure.

In [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37597/1952), every subfigure occupies half text line, but the image inside every subfigure only uses 40% of available space. This creates the gap.

Following code shows the original answer and another where images inside subfigure use the whole available space. And there is no gap!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]