# Posting figures side by side

Tags: floats

[image: I want the two pictures side by side.]I want to post two figures side by side in latex but it results coming one after the another. How do I solve this? The code i used is:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{img.jpg}
    \caption{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 44.6}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img2.jpg}
    \caption{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 45.9}
    \end{figure}
    \FloatBarrier
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: you apparently told to TeX, that they must be one after the other (by empty lines between, by to wide image, etc). you should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which exhibit your problem. Than we be able to help you.

Comment: First, a blank line will always start a new paragraph,.  Second \caption starts and ends with a \par and takes up the whole width.  Just put them into minipages, usually separated by \hfill.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities, see [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [LaTeX figures side by side [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side?noredirect=1&lq=1).
For example with the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) (page 99) package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[style=plain]{floatrow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \CommonHeightRow{%
            \begin{floatrow}[2]%
                \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-a}}
                {\caption{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 44.6}}
                \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-b}}
                {\caption{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 45.9}}
            \end{floatrow}}%
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to delete the caption label, you can use the command `\caption*{}` or put `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}` in your preamble:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[style=plain]{floatrow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \CommonHeightRow{%
            \begin{floatrow}[2]%
                \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-a}}
                {\caption*{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 44.6}}
                \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\includegraphics[height=\CommonHeight]{example-image-b}}
                {\caption*{Energy Vs Photon Count graph for day 45.9}}
            \end{floatrow}}%
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Nako

Comment: It also says that the floatrow package doesn't support the \caption*{} command. Is there a solution for this too?

Comment: @ Nirashan Pradhan, where does it say that (page number)? In my example it does, see please the edited answer. Have you tried to compile it?