# Two pictures side by side in the two columns format

Tags: diagrams

I would like to put two pictures side by side in the two-column template as follows.

[image: expected]

This is the current code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5 in]{square.jpg}
    \caption{the square is blue}
    \label{fig:square}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5 in]{circle.jpg}
    \caption{the circle is orange}
    \label{fig:circle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Then, the result is as follows.

[image: current result]

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, this problem has already been answered, kindly check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495253/posting-figures-side-by-side

Comment: The important point is that you can put two captions into one figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is use of `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} CC @{}}
    \includegraphics[width=1.5 in]{example-image-duck}%{square.jpg}
    \caption{the square is blue}
    \label{fig:square}
    &   \includegraphics[width=1.5 in]{example-image-duck}%{circle.jpg}
        \caption{the circle is orange}
        \label{fig:circle}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will meet the requirement:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\hbox{\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=0.25in]{example-image} \caption{the
square is blue} \label{fig:square} 
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{12pt}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=0.25in]{example-image} \caption{the
circle is orange} \label{fig:circle}  
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}}
}
\end{document}
```