# How to correct the appearance of the captions

Tags: spacing, floats, formatting, captions

I followed a [tutorial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) I saw on this website, but the captions don't look right because they are too long.

This is the code I used:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/chapter_3/p_type_materials_2012.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure of merit of p-type semiconductors}
    \label{fig:p-type-zT}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/chapter_3/n_type_materials_2012.png}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure of merit of n-type semiconductors}
    \label{fig:n-type-zT}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

And it looks like this:
[image: The captions are too close together]

How can I correct this? How can I add a space in between or, if not possible for instance, send the "semicon-" to the next line? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make both minipages smaller (`0.45\textwidth`for example)  and add `\hfill` between them.

Comment: @leandriis a empty space instead of the `%` should sufficient, no ?

Comment: @BambOo: It depends on the width and the desired output. Without the `\hfill` the cpations might still end up quite close to each other.

Comment: reduce font size for caption

Comment: @jsbibra: This will cause inconsistencies thoroughout the document and one would have to reduce the font size quite a lot to actually get some space between the captions. To summarize: I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- Get rid of all 3 `\centering` directives.
- Reduce the widths of both `minipage` environments from `0.5\textwidth` to `0.45\textwidth`. (Use
- Insert the directive `\hfill` at the end of the first `minipage` environment.
- In the list of optional arguments of both `\includegraphics` statements, replace `height=5cm` with `width=\textwidth`.
- Replace both instances of `\captionof{figure}` with `\caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{figures/chapter_3/p_type_materials_2012.png}
    \caption{Figure of merit of p-type semiconductors}
    \label{fig:p-type-zT}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{figures/chapter_3/n_type_materials_2012.png}
    \caption{Figure of merit of n-type semiconductors}
    \label{fig:n-type-zT}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```