# Drawing two table inside a box with some text

Tags: tables

I want to draw the image attached below. I am trying with latex as per the code given below. I have been able to draw the tables but not getting how to put them side by side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
*&$-1$&$-i$&$-j$ \\
\hline
$-1$&$1$&$i$&$j$\\
\hline
$-i$&$-1$&$-1$&$l$\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
*&$-1$&$-i$&$-j$ \\
\hline
$-1$&$1$&$i$&$j$\\
\hline
$-i$&$-1$&$-1$&$l$\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) question for how to put figures side by side. If you want the caption to be independent of the placement of the figures, you might find the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package helpful. After that, you can wrap the entire thing in a `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` environment. The horizontal rules above and below the text you can achieve with `\rule` or `\hrule`.

Answer (score 2):

You  can nest two tabulars inside a larger tabular, and put it in a `figure` environment if it has to be considered as such. Here is a way to do that, with the help of some packages.

To frame the whole figure, you can use a boxed  minipage (width determined by trial and error) in the place of the figure environment, and use `\captionof{figure}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
```

\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{caption}

```
\begin{document}

 \centering\setlength{\fboxsep}{2em}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{8.9cm}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
       \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{$}Sl<{$}|}}
        \hline at
        *&-1 & -i & -j \\
        \hline
        -1 & 1 & i & j \\
        \hline
        -i & -1 & -1 & l \\
        \hline
    \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{(G, * )}
        \end{tabular} & \qquad &
       \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{$}Sl<{$}|}@{}}
        \hline
        *& -1 & -i & -j \\
        \hline
         -1 & 1 & i & j \\
        \hline
         -i & -1 & -1 & l \\
        \hline
    \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{(H, + )}
        \end{tabular} \\[8ex]
    \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\text{Some text}}\\
    \midrule
    \end{tabular}
  \captionof{figure}{Text}
 \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How to put it inside a box as shown in the picture?

Comment: @niceguy: I've edited my code. Is it like you want?