# How could one place 2 or more Circuit diagrams reproduced through tikz next to each other and not above?

Tags: luatex

```
%Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2cm, bottom = 4 cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
% ============= Packages =============

% Dokumentinformationen
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={Titel der Abschlussarbeit},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={Euer Name},
    pdfkeywords={}, 
    %Links nicht einrahmen
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}

% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox,subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}X<{$}}
\usepackage{caption}



%Für Tikz
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



% zusätzliche Schriftzeichen der American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape,european 
    voltages,circuit ee 
    IEC, font=\sffamily\footnotesize,cute inductor]
    
    \def\ctikzscaledim#1#2{% #1: scale 
        %factor, #2: parameter
        \edef\otmp{\ctikzvalof{#2}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{(\otmp)*(#1))}%
        \pgfkeyslet{\circuitikzbasekey/#2}{\tmp}}
        \def\ctikzscalediodes#1{%
        \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/height}
        \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/width}
    }
    \ctikzscalediodes{0.5}
    \draw
    % DC sources
    (0,0) to [sV,v^<=$U_{Ein}$] (0,1.5) 
    coordinate (Upp) 
    to [L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$,-*] ++ (3.5,0) 
    coordinate (NE) 
    ++(0,1.72) node (mosfet1) 
    [nigfete,anchor=D,bodydiode]{$S_1$} 
    coordinate (DS1)
    ++(0,-3.5) node (mosfet2) 
    [nigfete,anchor=D,bodydiode] {$S_2$} 
    coordinate 
    (SS2)
    (mosfet1.E) -- (mosfet2.C)
    (mosfet1.C) -| (5.5,3.2) to 
    [D*,l=$D_1$,*-] (5.5,0.5) to 
    [D*,l=$D_2$,-*] 
    (5.5,-2.05) -| (mosfet2.E) (5.5,0) 
    to[short,*-] (0,0)
    (5.5,-2.05) -| (7.5,3.2) to 
    [C,l_=$C$,*-*] (7.5,-2.05) 
    (5.5,3.2) -- (7.5,3.2) 
    (7.5,3.2) to [short,-o] (9.5,3.2) 
    coordinate (a)
    (7.5,-2.05) to [short,-o] 
    (9.5,-2.05) coordinate (b)
    (a) to [open,v=$U_{Aus}$, voltage=straight] ++ 
    (b,-5)  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Version (a) der Totem-Pole Topologie}
\label{Totem_1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape,european 
    voltages,circuit ee 
    IEC, 
    cute inductor]
    \tikzset{GaN hemt/.style={hemt,
            circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/base height=0.6, length of the 
            "base" 
            vertical 
            bar circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/gate height=0.5, distance of 
            the 
            S/D 
            terminals circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/bodydiode conn=0.85, 
            attachment 
            point of body diode circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/gate 
            asym=-0.1, 
            slightly 
            down circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/split gate=true, split gate 
            circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/source arrow=1, right-facing arrow
        }
    }
    
}
\def\ctikzscaledim#1#2{% #1: scale factor, #2: parameter
    \edef\otmp{\ctikzvalof{#2}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{(\otmp)*(#1))}%
    \pgfkeyslet{\circuitikzbasekey/#2}{\tmp}
}

\def\ctikzscalediodes#1{%
    \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/height}
    \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/width}
    
}
\ctikzscalediodes{0.5}

\draw
% DC sources
(0,0) to [sV,v^<=$U_{Ein}$] (0,1.5) coordinate (Upp) 
to [L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$] ++ (3.5,0) coordinate (NE) 


% Switches and diodes for leg a
++(0,0.72) node [GaN hemt,name=GaN1] {$S_1$} coordinate (DS1)
++(0,-3.5) node [GaN hemt,name=GaN2] {$S_2$} coordinate (SS2)


% --Switch connections for leg a
(NE) to[short,*-] (GaN1.E)
(GaN1.E) -- (GaN2.C)
(GaN1.C) -| (5.5,3) to [D*,l=$D_1$,*-] (5.5,0.5) to [D*,l=$D_2$,-*] 
(5.5,-2.05) -- 
(GaN2.E)
(5.5,0) to[short,*-] (0,0)
(GaN1.C) -| (7.4,2.97) to [C,l_=$C$,*-*] (7.4,-2.05) |- (GaN2.E)
(GaN1.C) to [short,-o] (9.4,2.989) coordinate (a)
(GaN2.E) to [short,-o] (9.4,-2.05) coordinate (b)
(a) to [open,v=$U_{Aus}$, voltage=straight] ++ (f,-5)

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Version (b) der Totem-Pole Topologie}
\label{Totem2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape,european voltages,circuit 
ee IEC, 
font=\sffamily\footnotesize,cute inductor]

\tikzset{GaN hemt/.style={hemt,
        circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/base height=0.6, length of the 
        "base" 
        vertical 
        bar circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/gate height=0.5, distance of 
        the S/D 
        terminals circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/bodydiode conn=0.85, 
        attachment 
        point of body diode circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/gate 
        asym=-0.1, 
        slightly 
        down circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/split gate=true, split gate 
        circuitikz/tripoles/hemt/source arrow=1, right-facing arrow
    }
}
\def\ctikzscalediodes#1{%
    \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/height}
    \ctikzscaledim{#1}{bipoles/diode/width}
}
\ctikzscalediodes{0.5}
\draw
% DC sources
(0,0) to [sV,v^<=$U_{Ein}$] (0,1.5) coordinate (Upp) 
to [L, l=$L$, i=$i_L$] ++ (3.5,0) coordinate (NE) 


% Switches and diodes for leg a
++(0,0.72) node [GaN hemt,name=GaN1] {$S_1$} 
++(0,-3) node [GaN hemt,name=GaN2] {$S_2$}


%   % --Switch connections for leg a
(NE) to[short,*-] (GaN1.E)
(GaN1.E) -- (GaN2.C)

%   % Switches and diodes for leg b
(NE)++(2,0.75)
++(0,0.75) node (mosfet1) [nigfete,anchor=D,bodydiode] {$S_3$}
++(0,-3) node (mosfet2) [nigfete,anchor=D,bodydiode] {$S_4$}
%
%   % --Switch connections for leg b
(GaN1.C) to[short,-*] (mosfet1.C) coordinate (a)
%   (GaN1.E) -| (mosfet1.C)
(mosfet1.E) -- (mosfet2.C)
(mosfet2.C) to[short,*-] (0,0)
(GaN2.E) to[short,-*] (mosfet2.E) coordinate (b) 

%   Capacitor
(a) -| ++ (1.5,0) coordinate (c)
to [C, l_=$C$, *-*] ++ (0,-4.55) |- (b) coordinate (d)

(c) to [short,-o] ++ (2,0) coordinate (e)

(d) to [short,-o] ++ (3.5,0) coordinate (f)

(e) to [open,v=$U_{Aus}$, voltage=straight] ++ (f,-4.5)  


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Version (c) der Totem-Pole Topologie}
\label{Totem3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which compiles? Besides: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side

Comment: Not related to the problem, but do not mix `circuitikz` with the internal Ti*k*Z circuit library. Choose one or the other (and I think you are using *very* old things --- the classes introduced before 1.0 makes all those scaling and mingling with internal quantity unnecessary).

Comment: About the problem: you have two floating figures, which will float independently. If you want them side-by-side, you have to put them into the same figure, maybe using a sub-figure package like `subfigure` or `subcaption`.