# Removing an "Overfull \vbox" message caused by a nested table

Tags: tables, boxes, warnings

I am trying to typeset a nested table, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}{*}{
      \begin{minipage}{3cm}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
          \hline
          A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st}\bigstrut[t] \\
          \hline
          A & A \\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}
        } &  A \\
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This causes a bad box: `Overfull \vbox (3.19998pt too high) detected at line 19`

I have been trying for a while to detect the precise source of this bad box (it's caused partly by the `\bigstrut`), but I do not know how to remove this warning. I tried various fixes of the sort `\\[3.5pt]`, but I am not sure what's going wrong and how to address the issue. It might be the case that typesetting the table in an entirely different way turns out to be the "best" way, but for now I am interested in the source of the bad box and how to get rid of it.

Note: In this minimized example, the bottom middle A overlaps with the nested table, but even if I do something like `\\[1cm]` for the second-to-last line, the bad (overfull) `\vbox` message persists (with incidentally the same point size indication).

---

**EDIT**

Here's is an alternate MWE which creates a similar overfull error without having to read through a nested `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\vstrut}[3][blue]{{\color{#1}\rule[-#2]{0.4pt}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\hstrut}[2][blue]{{\color{#1}\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-0.4pt]{#2}{0.4pt}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A\vstrut{0ex}{5ex} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
            Trial \vstrut[red]{18pt}{18pt}  text
      \end{minipage}} 
                                          & A \\
   A\vstrut{3ex}{3ex}\hstrut{1.65in} & {} & A \\
   A                                 & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any bad boxes. Are you using a different class/page size?

Comment: @percuße I compile it with `pdflatex` (`pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13`) and get 0 errors, 0 warnings, and 1 bad box. My default is letter (not A4) where I am right now, but I'd be surprised if that mattered.

Comment: It seems that the height of the `\multirow` is not correctly determined.  Test this out by using the package `lipsum` and then replace the contents of the `minipage` environment with just `\lipsum[1]`

Comment: @tohecz You've added the tag "warnings"; I'm not disagreeing, but technically I'm getting "Warnings: 0" (!) and "Bax Boxes: 1". Just noting this for those good at editing tags, in case it matters.

Comment: @LoverofStructure That's what your IDE says to you I think; it's true that bad boxes aren't shown as `Warning:`, still they belong to that category I think ;)

Comment: @tohecz I agree with you. It's a bit confusing, though I guess there is value in this separation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX is right: the overfull box (3.2pt too high) should be there: the embedded table you are trying to fit in the height of two outer table rows is just too high. What made it too high?  First, you have used the `\bigstrut[t]` in the *embedded* table. This has made it 2pt higher.  Second, you have used three `\hlines`, each being `\arrayrulewidth=0.4pt` high: this accounts for the remaining 1.2pt.

A test: The inner table fits perfectly if the `bigstrut[t]` and `\hline`s are removed:

[image: no bigstrut or hline]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%|
          %\hline
          A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st}%
          %\bigstrut[t]
          \\
          %\hline
          A & A \\
          %\hline
        \end{tabular}
        } &  A\\
   A & {} & A\\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

There is only one way of dealing with this: creating more space in the outer table.  Given that you would probably like the rows of the inner and outer table to be aligned, I suggest parallelism.  Whenever you use a `\bigstrut` in the inner table, use it in the outer table as well, in the same row.

There's a catch however.  Whenever you make a row of the outer table higher than normal, you need to tell `multirow` about it in order to not get an overfull box.  To do this, multirow provides the optional argument `bigstruts` that increases the height of the multirow cell for `bigstruts * \bigstrutjot`.  Thus (I've cleaned up the MWE a bit), an example with (only) `\bigstrut` in the inner table, and consequently a `\bigstrut` in the outer table plus the optional argument `[1]`.

[image: bigstrut, no hlines]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{\color{red}%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%|
          A & A\bigstrut[t] \\
          A & A\\
        \end{tabular}} &  A\bigstrut[t]  \\
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Next, `\hline` in the embedded table. First, parallelism: we have to get extra vertical space into the outer table as well. I propose using a strut of appropriate depth.

```
\def\hlinestrut{\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\arrayrulewidth]{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

However, this is not enough: again, we also have to tell multirow that the rows are higher than normal.  However, we are faced with a problem.  The only way to increase the height of the multirow cell is by the optional argument `bigstruts`, which takes only integer values, but the height of a `\hline` is not an integer multiple of `\bigstrutjot`. By default, `\arrayrulewidth` is one fifth of `\bigstrutjot`.  I see no other way but patch multirow to accept floats for the `bigstruts` argument. Furtunately, this is quite easy, all we have to change is this:

```
%\ifnum#2>0 \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
\ifdim#2pt>0pt \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
```

The full example now:

[image: bigstrut and one hline]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\hlinestrut{\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\arrayrulewidth]{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}}
\makeatletter
\def\@xmultirow#1[#2]#3[#4]#5{\@tempcnta=#1%
  \@tempdima\@tempcnta\ht\@arstrutbox
  \advance\@tempdima\@tempcnta\dp\@arstrutbox
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<0\@tempdima=-\@tempdima\fi
  \advance\@tempdima#2\bigstrutjot
  \if*#3\setbox0\vtop to \@tempdima{\vfill\multirowsetup
    \hbox{\strut#5\strut}\vfill}%
  \else
      \setbox0\vtop to \@tempdima{\hsize#3\@parboxrestore
                \vfill \multirowsetup \strut#5\strut\par\vfill}%
  \fi
  \ht0\z@\dp0\z@
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<0\advance\@tempdima-\dp\@arstrutbox
  \else\@tempdima\ht\@arstrutbox
     %\ifnum#2>0 \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
     \ifdim#2pt>0pt \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
  \fi
  \advance\@tempdima#4\relax\leavevmode\vtop{\vskip-\@tempdima\box0\vss}}
\@ifundefined{bigstrutjot}{\newdimen\bigstrutjot \bigstrutjot\jot}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}[1.2]{*}{\color{red}%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%|
          A & A\bigstrut[t] \\
          \hline
          A & A\\
        \end{tabular}} &  A\bigstrut[t]\hlinestrut  \\
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To go fully back to the original example (with three `\hlines`), one final complication: the top `\hline`s of the two tables should overlap.  First, we increase `bigstruts` to `1.6` (one `\bigstrut` and three `\hline`s). Second: the inner `\hline` is a part of the outer cell! So, if we do nothing, the inner table will be pushed `0.4pt` down. (And this will be too close to the cell in the third row.)  The solution is to use `\multirow`'s `fixup` optional parameter, which shifts the cell. (Omitting this optional parameter `[\arrayrulewidth]` means that the inside table is *not* shifted to have their top lines overlap.)

[image: bigstrut and three hlines]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\hlinestrut{\rule[\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\arrayrulewidth]{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}}
\makeatletter
\def\@xmultirow#1[#2]#3[#4]#5{\@tempcnta=#1%
  \@tempdima\@tempcnta\ht\@arstrutbox
  \advance\@tempdima\@tempcnta\dp\@arstrutbox
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<0\@tempdima=-\@tempdima\fi
  \advance\@tempdima#2\bigstrutjot
  \if*#3\setbox0\vtop to \@tempdima{\vfill\multirowsetup
    \hbox{\strut#5\strut}\vfill}%
  \else
      \setbox0\vtop to \@tempdima{\hsize#3\@parboxrestore
                \vfill \multirowsetup \strut#5\strut\par\vfill}%
  \fi
  \ht0\z@\dp0\z@
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<0\advance\@tempdima-\dp\@arstrutbox
  \else\@tempdima\ht\@arstrutbox
     %\ifnum#2>0 \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
     \ifdim#2pt>0pt \advance\@tempdima\bigstrutjot \fi
  \fi
  \advance\@tempdima#4\relax\leavevmode\vtop{\vskip-\@tempdima\box0\vss}}
\@ifundefined{bigstrutjot}{\newdimen\bigstrutjot \bigstrutjot\jot}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}[1.6]{*}[\arrayrulewidth]{\color{red}%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%|
          \hline
          A & A\bigstrut[t] \\
          \hline
          A & A\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}} &  A\bigstrut[t]\hlinestrut  \\
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Another complication arises when you use (parallel) `\bigstrut`s but *not* in the first row. The thing is, `\multirow` automatically shifts the table for `\bigstrutjot` whenever the `bigstruts` argument is positive. However, this only makes sense if the `\bigstrut` occurs in the first row (I believe this is due to the fact that multirow uses `\vtop` top construct the cell content). So, in the situation described above, one must "unshift" the table using `fixup`, like so:

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A & \multirow{2}[1.6]{*}[\dimexpr\arrayrulewidth-\bigstrutjot]{\color{red}%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%|
          \hline
          A & A \\
          \hline
          A & A\bigstrut[t]\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}} &  A\hlinestrut  \\
   A & {} & A\bigstrut[t] \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting a result that is exactly like your last piece of code, except (1) with the inner table not shifted (i.e. without `[\arrayrulewidth]`) and (2) with the top two lines perfectly aligned?

Comment: No, I don't think so (unless you shift manually within the cell's content, of course): as I said above, the whole inner table, including the rules, is part of the outer cell's content and as such appears under the top rule.

Comment: To others: **Please also see the very good answer by user A.Ellett.**

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the same error is reproduced using the following text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\vstrut}[3][blue]{{\color{#1}\rule[-#2]{0.4pt}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\hstrut}[2][blue]{{\color{#1}\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-0.4pt]{#2}{0.4pt}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A\vstrut{0ex}{5ex} & \multirow{2}{3cm}{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
            Trial \vstrut[red]{18pt}{18pt}  text
      \end{minipage}} 
                                          & A \\
   A\vstrut{3ex}{3ex}\hstrut{1.65in} & {} & A \\
   A                                 & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\multirow` creates a `\vtop` box whose height and depth are set according to the rules for `\vtop` and the height and depth of `\@arstrutbox`.  Now, `\@arstrutbox` is a box set up when a tabular environment is create.  It is set to be a box whose height and depth are `\arraystretch` times the height and depth of a normal strut.

By playing with the visible struts in the above example, you can see the effects of how `\multirow` creates the box for its content.  For example, even though you can place a strut to extend the size of the second row, this does not prevent an overfull box error when the strut **inside** the `\multirow` command force the contents of the box created by `\multirow` to be **too** big.

So, one solution would be to reset the value of `\arraystretch`.  But that seems a bit of overkill:  you probably don't want to change the `\arraystretch` of the **whole** table to fix just one box.

Keeping in mind how `\multirow` creates its box means a couple of things.  Consider this next example where I tell `\multirow` that I only need one row.

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A\vstrut{0ex}{5ex} & \multirow{1}{3cm}{%
      \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{3cm}
            Trial \vstrut[red]{18pt}{18pt}  text
      \end{minipage}} 
                                          & A \\
   A\vstrut{3ex}{3ex}\hstrut{1.65in} & {} & A \\
   A                                 & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

You can completely forgo using `\multirow` by creating a top aligning `minipage` of zero height.

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A\vstrut{0ex}{5ex} &% 
      {\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{3cm}
            Trial \vstrut[red]{18pt}{18pt}  text
      \end{minipage}} 
                                          & A \\
   A\vstrut{3ex}{3ex}\hstrut{1.65in} & {} & A \\
   A                                 & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Avoiding `\multirow`, you can still achieve  something more like your original example, you can write:

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A &% 
      {\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{3cm}
          \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st} \\
            \hline
            A & A \\
            \hline
          \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}} 
          & A \\
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

It seems the benefits of using `\multirow` is the ability to center its content with respect to the other rows it's supposed to straddle (see edit toward the end of this answer).  So, here's an example that comes closer to what you want.  (I've added a `\hrule` to better show the *mis*alignment of the horizontal lines.)

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A &% 
      \multirow{2}{*}%
      {\begin{minipage}[c][0pt]{3cm}%
          \begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|}
            \hline
            A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st} \\
            \hline
            A & A \\
            \hline
          \end{tabular}%
      \end{minipage}} 
          & A \\\hline
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Remember that `tabular` environments, much like `minipage`s, can be centered with respect to the line they fall on.

To get the horizontal lines to align properly, add a vertical strut inside the `minipage` as follows (in this example, I use `\raisebox` to create a box of zero total height+depth):

```
\begin{tabular}{|lll|}
  \hline
   A &% 
      \multirow{2}{*}%
      {\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\vspace{0.5pt}%
          \begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|}
            %\hline % commented-out from original code b/c it slightly struts out at the top
            A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st} \\
            \hline
            A & A \\
            \hline
          \end{tabular}%
      \end{minipage}}} 
          & A \\\hline
   A & {} & A \\
   A & A  & A \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

One additional point, you've got some whitespace creeping into your document at the end of the lines.  This is causing widths to not quite be what you're defining them to be.  I've eliminated a number of the more egregious occurrences.

**EDIT**

As @SašoŽivanović has pointed out, `\multirow` doesn't *center* its content.  But what I'm talking about regarding centering is that `\multirow` will *essentially* center the contents of a box whose total height and depth is zero.  This is because the contents of the `\vtop` used in the definition of `\multirow` are bracketted between `\vfill`s resulting in content that is centered with respect to the expected  height generated by the rows to be spanned.

**Whitespace**

In your original post you called

```
A & \multirow{2}{*}{
  \begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      A & \hfill 1\textsuperscript{st}\bigstrut[t] \\
      \hline
      A & A \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
    }
```

This is adding extra space at the line beginning `\multirow...` and it's adding extra space at the end when you write `\end{minipage}`.  Look at my examples where I avoid this through placing `%` or closing arguments earlier than you do.

For more details on this, I suggest reading @egreg's answers posted to [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74541/22413)

Comment: I beg to disagree on the statement that "`multirow` doesn't correctly adjust the box height". First, `multirow` doesn't adjust the row heights at all (*if* that was what you meant). Second, the strut's depth of `18pt` in the alternative MWE is simply too large: the correct depth to reach the bottom of the second row would be `2\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox`, which is `15.6pt`. The difference is precisely `2.4pt` reported by the overfull box warning.  Another issue: it is clear from the code of `\multirow` that it doesn't center the content, but rather top-aligns it using `\vtop`.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović  I chose `18pt` because the strut is still well within the second row and yet there's an overfull box error.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Saying "adjust" was probably not a wish choice of words.

Comment: Yes but if you make the strut `15.6pt` deep the overfull box is gone!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at!

Comment: Sorry, then I have lost you. ---But regarding centering, you were certainly right! I have missed those `\vfill`s ...

Comment: Could you elaborate on your paragraph about whitespace at the end of lines? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I've updated my answer.  I hope the update clarifies things a bit better.