# Multirow cells with centered multiline text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating, multirow, tabu

I use `tabu` package to easily typeset tables. Now i need to typeset long table. So i used `longtabu`. The head of the table consists of much columns. Also there are lots of text in each cell and some cells should be spanned. As i think, the centered text (formatted as paragraph) would look better.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}


\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{90} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}%


\begin{document}

\newlength{\firsttoprow}
\setlength{\firsttoprow}{3cm}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth%
  {|X[25,C]%
    |X[15,C]|X[15,C]|X[15,C]%
    |X[25,C]%
    |X[25,C]|}
  \caption{First table caption%
  \label{tab:first}}\\\hline
  \multirow{2}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Column A (first page head)}}%
  & \rot{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column B}}%
  & \rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column C (two lines)}}%
  & \rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column D (two lines)}}%
  & \multirow{2}*{\rot[90][7.5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column E (consists of three lines)}}}%
  & \multirow{2}*{\rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column F (two lines)}}}\\\cline{2-4}
  & B (two lines)%
  & C (three lines)%
  & D & &\\\hline
  \endfirsthead
  \caption*{Table \ref{tab:first} (Cont.)}\\\hline
  Column A (head)%
  & B  & C  & D%
  & Col. E%
  & Col. F\\\hline
  \endhead
  Cont A%
  & Cnt.B  & Cnt.C  & Cnt.D%
  & Cnt.E%
  & Cnt.F\\\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: table with spanned multiline cells]

The rotation is made with `xparse` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32687/33087). There are problems:

1. At the top row in columns B, C and D bottom vertical space between box and horizontal line is bigger. I want content to be at the middle of cell.
2. Content of spanned head cells (columns A, E and F) vertically alligned by `\multirow` so the centers of boxes are located at the line between rows of head. I want the centers of boxes are located at centers of spanned cells.
3. This example produces 6 bad boxes (overfull `\vbox` due to `\multirow`).

The second example provides ugly workaround with manual vertical fixups and without `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}



\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\strut\hspace{0pt}}X[#1]<{\hspace{0pt}\strut}}
\tabucolumn Y

\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{90} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}%



\begin{document}

\newlength{\firsttoprow}
\newlength{\fixuptoprow}
\setlength{\firsttoprow}{3cm}
\setlength{\fixuptoprow}{2cm}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth%
  {|Y{25,C}%
    |Y{15,C}|Y{15,C}|Y{15,C}%
    |Y{25,C}%
    |Y{25,C}|}
  \caption{First table caption%
  \label{tab:first}}\\\hline
  \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}\vspace{-\fixuptoprow}\vspace{3.5ex}%
   \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Column A (first page head)}%
  \end{minipage}%
  & \rot{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column B}}%
  & \rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column C (two lines)}\hspace{1ex}}%
  & \rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column D (two lines)}}%
  & \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{7.5ex}\vspace{-\fixuptoprow}%
     \rot[90][7.5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column E (consists of three lines)}}%
    \end{minipage}%
  & \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{5ex}\vspace{-\fixuptoprow}%
     \rot[90][5ex]{\parbox{\firsttoprow}{\centering Column F (two lines)}}%
    \end{minipage}\\\cline{2-4}
  & B (two lines)%
  & C (three lines)%
  & D & &\\\hline
  \endfirsthead
  \caption*{Table \ref{tab:first} (Cont.)}\\\hline
  Column A (head)%
  & B  & C  & D%
  & Col. E%
  & Col. F\\\hline
  \endhead
  Cont A%
  & Cnt.B  & Cnt.C  & Cnt.D%
  & Cnt.E%
  & Cnt.F\\\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope someone can suggest beautiful decision which calculates fixups automatically. Also, for `minipage` decision see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99684/33087.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a much simpler markup, and do away with the vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage{type1ec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}


\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{ \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular} }}



\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{
>{\centering}m{2cm}
>{\centering}m{2cm}
>{\centering}m{2cm}
>{\centering}m{2cm}
>{\centering}m{2cm}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
}
  \caption{First table caption%
  \label{tab:first}}\\\hline
Column A (first page head)
  & \rot{Column B}\par\hrule\smallskip B (two lines)
  & \rot{Column C\\ (two lines)}\par\hrule\smallskip C (three lines)
  & \rot{Column D\\ (two lines)}\par\hrule\smallskip D\\\mbox{}
  & \rot{Column E\\ (consists of\\ three lines)}
  & \rot{Column F\\ (two lines)}\\
\hline
  \endfirsthead
  \caption*{Table \ref{tab:first} (Cont.)}\\\hline
  Column A (head)%
  & B  & C  & D%
  & Col. E%
  & Col. F\\\hline
  \endhead
  Cont A%
  & Cnt.B  & Cnt.C  & Cnt.D%
  & Cnt.E%
  & Cnt.F\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```