# Save command result in other command

Tags: macros, programming, variable

I am getting a value by a command. Now I am temporarily changing a saved variable which changes the command output. After I finished some code I want to reset the stored value if the value before the temporare code was 1.

My example can be stripped down to:

```
\newcommand{\storedvalue}{1}
\newcommand{\getstoredvalue}{\storedvalue}
\newcommand{\resetstoredvalue}{Resetting}

Some text

\let\oldvalue\protect\getstoredvalue
\renewcommand{\storedvalue}{0}

Some text which needs the stored value to be changed

\ifnum\numexpr\oldvalue>0%
    \resetstoredvalue{}%
\fi%
```

Of course the `\getstoredvalue` and the `\resetstoredvalue` are a lot more complicated.

I tried to use `\protect`. This will return the correct value, not the command. But I get `Missing number, treated as zero` in my `if`-clause.

I think this is a rather easy question. But I did not find a solution by googling. Also this may be because I was looking for the wrong searching term.

I hope somebody can help me or post a website where I can find the solution myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `\edef` the macro `\oldvalue` or use

```
\let\oldvalue\storedvalue
```

because `\let\oldvalue\getoldvalue` would make a copy of `\getoldvalue`, not of its expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\storedvalue}{1}
\newcommand{\getstoredvalue}{\storedvalue}
\newcommand{\resetstoredvalue}{Resetting}

Some text

\edef\oldvalue{\getstoredvalue} % or \let\oldvalue\storedvalue
\renewcommand{\storedvalue}{0}

Some text which needs the stored value to be changed

\ifnum\oldvalue>0
    \resetstoredvalue{}%
\fi

\end{document}
```

Note that no `%` should appear after `0` in `\ifnum` context.

[image]

Comment: `\edef` works perfectly. Thank you very much. I cannot save the `\storedvalue` because in my real code the command is not simply returning the value. - One more question: Why should I leave the `%` after the `0`? I read this very often so I was thinking this is the "convention" to do it.

Comment: @miile7 See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/