# Can't override tcolorbox title style if it's a Section title

Tags: tcolorbox, section-titles

#### Updates

Added not-working-workarounds plus an additional MWE.

## Problem

I use a tcolorbox as a Chapter's summary, and thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35433/creating-unnumbered-chapters-sections-plus-adding-them-to-the-toc-and-or-header/35436#35436) I am able to include it in the TOC as well.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks
}
% ---------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{one}
\lipsum
\section{two}
\lipsum

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title={\protect\section*{Summary}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}},
    fonttitle=\ttfamily\bfseries\large,
    width=\textwidth+10mm,
    left skip=10mm,
    before skip=10mm,
    toptitle=4mm,
    boxsep=2mm,
    coltitle=white,
    colback=orange!5!white, 
    colframe=orange,
]

Lorem Ipsum

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

### My goal

All is fine, except that I would like to change the font family, size and color of the Summary title, but I can't: it always reverts to the default Section's. Unless I use a standard title, e.g. `title=Summary of the Chapter`, but then I lose the TOC entry that I need.

### Workarounds that don't really work

If I use `titlesec` then I can successfully change the section/tcolorbox title style, but then the link in the TOC points to the wrong section:

```
\documentclass[
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks
}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChapterSize{\@setfontsize\Huge{25}{27}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\SectionSize{\@setfontsize\Huge{22}{24}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\ChapterSize\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\thechapter{}}
{5mm}
{}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\thesection}
{5mm}
{}


% ---------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{one}
\lipsum
\section{two}
\lipsum


\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title={\protect\section*{Summary}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}},
    fonttitle=\color{white},
    width=\textwidth+10mm,
    left skip=10mm,
    before skip=10mm,
    toptitle=4mm,
    boxsep=2mm,
    coltitle=white,
    colback=orange!5!white, 
    colframe=orange,
]

Lorem Ipsum

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The same result (offset link in the TOC entry) happens if I change the title of the `tcolorbox` removing the `\protect`, like:

```
title={Summary\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}}
```

---

How do I change the font title (family-size-color) keeping the same functionality I've already implemented?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you already try something like `title={Summary\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}}`?

Comment: It fixes the formatting but it messes up the links in the TOC (via hyperref), the Summary entry in the TOC points to the section before it. I guess the `\protect` is useful there for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527001/how-to-fix-table-of-contents-links-leading-to-incorrect-places-subsection-se#comment1333083_527059) you have to add `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline` in order to set the anchor for the link properly—in case the TOC points to a wrong section. This, in conjunction with the use of the `titlesec` package, let me change the font style while having a not-numbered entry in the TOC which link points to the right place.

### Working example

```
\documentclass[
    ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks
}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChapterSize{\@setfontsize\Huge{25}{27}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\SectionSize{\@setfontsize\Huge{22}{24}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\ChapterSize\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\thechapter{}}
{5mm}
{}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\thesection}
{5mm}
{}


% ---------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{one}
\lipsum
\section{two}
\lipsum


\begin{tcolorbox}[
    title={\protect\section*{Summary}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}},
    fonttitle=\color{white},
    width=\textwidth+10mm,
    left skip=10mm,
    before skip=10mm,
    toptitle=4mm,
    boxsep=2mm,
    coltitle=white,
    colback=orange!5!white, 
    colframe=orange,
]

Lorem Ipsum

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems good.