# Indent code without adding unwanted space

Tags: macros

I like to indent code for readability (who does not?). But it seems that it disturbs LaTeX (who thinks that indentations are spaces):

[image]

How could I indent my code without adding unwanted spaces?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\ImUnreadible}{ss+m+m}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\IfBooleanTF{#2}{#4}{#3}}{Let me check...}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ImReadable}{ss+m+m}{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      %% We force the display of the big text
      #4
    }{% We force the display of the small text
      #3
    }
  }{%
    Let me check...
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent A\ImUnreadible*{Short}{Long}B.\\
A\ImReadable*{Short}{Long}B.\\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the indenting that causes the extra space, it is the trailing spaces at the end of lines that causes it.  To avoid it, end macro-definition lines with `%` (exception: if a line of code ends with a control sequence, a trailing `%` is not required).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\ImUnreadible}{ss+m+m}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\IfBooleanTF{#2}{#4}{#3}}{Let me check...}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ImReadable}{ss+m+m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      %% We force the display of the big text
      #4%
    }{% We force the display of the small text
      #3%
    }%
  }{%
    Let me check...%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent A\ImUnreadible*{Short}{Long}B.\\
A\ImReadable*{Short}{Long}B.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now, thanks!

Comment: @tobiasBora Don't feel bad...we all have brain burps now and again.

Comment: Next you will want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/4301