# Incompatibility tabularray and quantikz

Tags: tabularray

When loading tabularray (only in recent CTAN, I needed to manually copy it with ninecolors in my system) together with quantikz, tabularray just crashes as reported here https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/156

```
ERROR: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  rows = {35pt}, columns = {35pt},
  rowsep = 1pt, colsep = 1pt, stretch = 0,
  cells = {c,font=\Huge},
  cell{odd}{even} = {azure7},
  cell{even}{odd} = {azure7},
  hlines, vlines,
}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, thanks David Carlisle! (feel free to write your own answer if you want me to accept it)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \catcode`\&=4
    \begin{tblr}{
        rows = {35pt}, columns = {35pt},
        rowsep = 1pt, colsep = 1pt, stretch = 0,
        cells = {c,font=\Huge},
        cell{odd}{even} = {azure7},
        cell{even}{odd} = {azure7},
        hlines, vlines,
      }
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
      a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you're inside `center`, the additional braces are not needed. The `%` after `4` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Wrong like useless, or wrong like harmful? I tend to protect all my code by grouping/commenting even if it may not be useful ^^ It can't harm right?

Comment: Wrong like harmful. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74541/4427

Answer (score 1):

The `quantikz` package makes the dubious decision to globally make `&` active and so conflicts with other packages that expect `&` to have its standard meaning are likely.

It does so in order to be able to internally call `tikzcd` as an argument to other commands (the `quantikz` environment, actually, which absorbs its contents through `\NewEnviron`), so as to avoid using `ampersand replacement`.

You can fix this behavior by absorbing the environment's content and change `&` to an active copy thereof. The standard category code of `&` is globally reinstated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


% fix the category code problem
\catcode`&=4

% change the quantikz environment
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{quantikz}{O{} +b}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__quantikz_body_tl { \tikzcd@ [#1] #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \& } { \cA\& } \l__quantikz_body_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__quantikz_body_tl
  \endtikzcd
 }{}
\tl_new:N \l__quantikz_body_tl

\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \gate{U} & \ctrl{1} & \swap{2} & \ctrl{1} & \qw \\
\lstick{$\ket{0}$} & \gate{H} & \targ{} & \octrl{-1} & \control{} & \qw & \octrl{1} & \qw \\
&&&&&\targX{} & \gate{U} & \qw
\end{quantikz}

\begin{tblr}{
  rows = {35pt}, columns = {35pt},
  rowsep = 1pt, colsep = 1pt, stretch = 0,
  cells = {c,font=\Huge},
  cell{odd}{even} = {azure7},
  cell{even}{odd} = {azure7},
  hlines, vlines,
}
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for information: the `quantikz` package suffers from `\expandafter` frenzy: there are 484 occurrences on a total of 811 lines.