# TikZ: Automatic Numbering of Nodes, \value{counterName}

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{xi}
\setcounter{xi}{0}

\newcommand{\foo}[0]{
    \addtocounter{xi}{1};
    \coordinate (x{\value{xi}}) at (1,2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foo{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Every time I call `\foo` I want a new node to be initialized, a new node with name "xK", where K is the value of the counter being increased automatically at each call.

Comment: Just use `\coordinate (x\the\value{xi}) at (1,2);`?  See [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter).  Is that what you are looking for as I am not sure exactly what you want to accomplish. And thanks for providing a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\coordinate (x\the\value{xi}) at (1,2);`.  The following shows that the two nodes were indeed created by the multiple calls to `\foo{}`:

[image]

### Reference:

- [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter)

### Notes (thanks to @GonzaloMedina):

- There is no need to set the counter to 0 - that is automatically done when creating a new counter.
- The definition of `\foo` could also be given like this: `\newcommand{\foo}{\stepcounter{xi}\coordinate (x\the\value{xi}) at (1,2);}`.
- No need to invoke `\foo` with an ending semicolon.

Having said that my *personal* preference is to initialize counters (programming habit), and to add a trailing `;` within `tikzpicture` after each statement. I would not normally terminate the definition of `\foo` with a `;` in which case the trailing `;` would be required.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{xi}
\setcounter{xi}{0}

\newcommand{\foo}[0]{
    \addtocounter{xi}{1};
    \coordinate (x\the\value{xi}) at (1,2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foo{};
    \foo{};

    \node [circle, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=3pt, fill=blue                 ] at (x1) {};
    \node [circle ,minimum size=6pt, inner sep=6pt, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5] at (x2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And your question is?

When running your code, I get an error message, because `\value{xi}` does not yield text, but just the counter itself.

Replacing `\value{xi}` with `\arabic{xi}` makes the error go away, but I can't fathom whether the problem is solved now.