# How can I set the table counter?

Tags: counters

I've got my little `examples` env with

```
\newlist{examples}{enumerate}{1}                          
\setlist[examples]{label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*, resume}
```

How do I use the same counter for the `table` env?

Comment: I believe that it is simply `table`. So, `\arabic{table}` should yields its value? I am not sure what you want to do with it though. To access it's value you should refer to [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter).

Comment: Based on your title, perhaps you are looking for `\setcounter{table}{<num>}` to change the value of the table counter to a specific number?

Comment: No, I want to sync the values of both counters - or use one counter for both envs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I may have misunderstood the question. But is it like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{examples}{enumerate}{1}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4}
\begin{examples}[label=(\thetable.\arabic*)]
  \item {text to center}
  \item {text to center}
\end{examples}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 \\\hline
    3 & 4 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is one table}\label{tab:mytab}
\end{table}

\begin{examples}[label=(\thetable.\arabic*)]
  \item {text to center}
  \item {text to center}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The settings of the list can be made global by

```
\setlist[examples]{label=(\thetable.\arabic*)}
```

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{examples}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examples]{label=(\thetable.\arabic*)}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{4}
\begin{examples}
  \item {text to center}
  \item {text to center}
\end{examples}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    1 & 2 \\\hline
    3 & 4 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is one table}\label{tab:mytab}
\end{table}

\begin{examples}
  \item {text to center}
  \item {text to center}
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

This will take the last value of `\thetable` as the first digit and second digit will be the usual arabic numbers.