# LaTeX: Different spaces when using readarray, whiledo and value

Tags: loops

***The answer of the following problem is given in Ulrikes Comment.
Thank you very much!***

I am trying to use external data for similar documents I have to write. 
The number of these data varies so I would like to use whildo or forloop, but both tools 
create too big spaces between the single data sets.

Thank you

Trillan

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{forloop}

%opening
\newarray\Test
\readarray{Test}{%
   Eintrag 1&%
   Eintrag 2&%
   Eintrag 3&%
   Eintrag 4
}%

\begin{document}

Normal Space:

\Test(2) \Test(3) \Test(4) \Test(1)

\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{1}

Big Space mit whiledo:
\whiledo {\value{i}  <  5}{%
   \Test(\value{i})%
   \stepcounter{i}
}%

A little bit better with forloop:

\forLoop[1]{1}{4}{i}{%
  \Test(\value{i})%
}

Without value everthing is working fine:

\setcounter{i}{1}
\whiledo {\value{i}  <  5}{%
   \Test(3) %
   \stepcounter{i}%
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\Test(\the\value{i})`. `\value` alone works only in some specific locations. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanx Trillan

Comment: @UlrikeFischer An answer?

Answer (score 5):

Use `\Test(\the\value{i})`. `\value` alone works only in some specific locations. See [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/what-is-the-proper-method-of-accessing-a-counter)