# Count Number of Labelled Equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, counters

Is there an easy way to get an accurate count of the number of equations that have identifiers?  If they are all auto generated than `\arabic{equation}` does the job, but equations can also have manually specified identifiers using `\tag`.

One solution would be to *simply* redefine `\tag` to increment some other counter and then sum that counter and `\arabic{equation}` at the end.  However, it turns out that this is not quite as *simple* as my failed attempt below shows.

The MWE below yields an incorrect count of one when it should be two.  Also, not sure if there any other common way to add identifiers to equations.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{taggedEquations}
\let\OldTag\tag
\renewcommand*{\tag}[1]{\stepcounter{taggedEquations}\OldTag{#1}}


\begin{document}
Auto numbered
\begin{align}
    y &= 2x 
\end{align}
Manually labelled
\begin{align}
    y &= x \tag{x}\label{eq:foo}
\end{align}
\addtocounter{taggedEquations}{\arabic{equation}}
Numbered Equations = \arabic{taggedEquations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, by "labels" you don't necessarily mean `\label`s.  Or do you mean `\label`s?.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Yes, I do not mean `\label` as you can "number" an equation but never refer to it (so don't need a `\label`). Does that make sense?  Have edited the question to _not_ use "label".

Comment: To me it seems that the incrementation of the tagged equation counter is local, hence is forgotten outside the `align`. Try `\arabic{taggedEquations}` after your last equation. It will print zero.

Comment: ... even though it really should not be like that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than hook into the user-level `tag` command it's probably better to hook into the lower level tag formatting command used by all tags whether automatic or from `\tag`. Also you need to account for the fact that AMS alignments are executed twice, to measure alignment widths.

Since `\eqref` also uses `\maketag@@@` (via `\tagform@`), setting `\measuring@true` ensures that the counter is not incremented when equation are referenced.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{taggedEquations}
\makeatletter
\def\eqref#1{{\textup{\measuring@true\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}}%
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{%
\ifmeasuring@\else
  \stepcounter{taggedEquations}%
\fi
\m@th\normalfont#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Auto numbered
\begin{align}
    y &= 2x 
\end{align}
Manually labelled
\begin{align}
    y &= x \tag{x}\label{eq:foo}
\end{align}
Equation Reference: \eqref{eq:foo}

Numbered Equations = \arabic{taggedEquations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be shorter if you say: `\let\ams@maketag@@@\maketag@@@\renewcommand*\maketag@@@{\stepcounter{taggedEquations}\ams@maketag@@@}` :)

Comment: ... and like the pedant I am I'd rather name the counter like `\newcounter{totalEquations}` at this point. +1 anyways!

Comment: @Ruben at which point?

Comment: Now that there is only one counter to count them all.

Comment: @Ruben your redefinition misses the \if@measuring test

Comment: oh you meant the name of the counter at a point in time, I thought you meant at that (some) point in the code:-)

Comment: Right :) and true that. For some silly reason I thought that the original macro would perform this test. Ok let's "agree" on: `\makeatletter\newcounter{totalEquations}\let\ams@maketag@@@\maketag@@@\renewcommand*\maketag@@@{\ifmeasuring@\else\stepcounter{totalEquations}\fi\ams@maketag@@@}\makeatother`.

Comment: Just realized that this is _also_ counting equation references. So adding `\eqref{eq:foo}` to the end results in the counter being reported as `3` instead of the desired `2`.

Comment: @PeterGrill probably `\def\tagform@#1{{\measuring@true\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}\fi}` is simplest (untested:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Above gives `Illegal parameter number in definition of \tagform@.`. Also, not sure why there is a `\fi` as there is not an `if`. And if `\measuring@true` is set, then isn't this going to _always_ ignore the space taken up by the equation label when measuremesnts of size are computed?

Comment: @PeterGrill sorry delete the fi actually you want to set th emeasuring flag in eqref not tagform (eqref doesn't measure anyway but setting it will stop the counting, I'll post somethin tomorrow if you've not fixed it by then (feel free to edit the answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Have corrected it as you suggested. Please have a look to ensure that I didn't miss something.

Comment: @PeterGrill - In the line immediately before `\end{document}`, might `\thetaggedEquations` be more straightforward than `\arabic{taggedEquations}`?

Comment: @Mico: I have been following the answers at [What is the proper method of accessing a counter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21561/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill - I was assuming that the definition of `\thetaggedEquations` wasn't going to be changed from its initial setting (set by `\newcounter`). However, this assumption may not be valid.

Comment: @Mico: Yep, you are correct. I just stick to using `\arabic{}` wheneber I need an actual value, so I don't have to think if the definition will be changed or not.